# Displaying a visual indicator while a synchronous function is running

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a function called `compute()` that does a bunch of computations and then updates the values of an HTML table, triggered by a `click()` event. This is not an ajax call, just several `for` loops.

What I'd like to do is provide a visual indicator that the computation is running. Something like modifying the opacity of the table. I thought that something like the following could work :

```
$("#mytable").css("opacity", "0.5");
compute();
$("#mytable").css("opacity", "1");
```

But when I use this code the opacity does not seem to be modified.

Any hint on how to do this ?

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried `$("#mytable").css("opacity", 0.5);`? Just a guess anyways...

Comment: have you tried reverting the opacity at the end of compute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the UI is not updated between the modification of the opacity and the `compute();` function. UI is updated once a while, not after every line of code (that would slow everything down).

You can use a timeout to bypass that: `setTimeout(compute, 0);`.

That way your UI get's updated before running `compute()`. You do have to put the third line, where you modify the opacity back to 1, in that function because it will run before `compute()` is done.

```
$("#mytable").css("opacity", "0.5");
setTimeout(compute, 0);

function compute() {
    ...

    $("#mytable").css("opacity", "1");
}
```

It might look dirty at first, but it is a genuine way to make sure your UI is updated!

Comment: Ah, yes, this works ! In fact I already tried something like this, but I left the parentheses : `setTimeout(compute(), 0);` And this does not work. Thanks a lot !

Comment: You are very welcome @juba. The setTimeout and setInterval method require a function. You can set a function inline: `setTimeout(function() { /* do stuff */ }, 1000);` or use the function name: `setTimeout(function_name, 1000);`. If you add the parentheses, the argument will be set whatever the function returns.

Comment: Just to clarify why this doesn't work if you let the parentheses : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058996/why-does-calling-settimeout-with-parenthesis-not-start-a-new-callstack

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is because your compute() function executes so quickly that you don't perceive the opacity changes.

Try to place a break-point in compute(), let us know whether the opacity changed.

Answer (score 0):

All client side implementations of JavaScript are single threaded, so you can't really expect the function-call `compute` to carry on running while the next statement is being executed.
If you want you could use a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers), though, to sort-of spawn a background thread.

After reading your question a second time, I must say that @tomdemuyt could very well be right: it's very likely that `compute` executes so quickly that the opacity is changed twice in a split second, so fast that you hardly notice it changing. also, since this is an event handler, you might want to consider this:

```
function compute(e)
{
    $(this).css({opacity:'.5'});
    //rest of your code
    $(this).css({opacity:'1'});
}
$('#mytable').on('click',compute);
```

which is just a bit more tidy IMO - it could be that this is not applicable to your code, but just in case...