# JS function does not update with the current time when called with setInterval

Tags: javascript

I have a time calculator that I would like to make update every minute. I made a special function to calculate the time for each time zone, <strike>but when I use setTimeout() to call the function manualTime();, it seems that it does not call solveTime(); for any variable (it used to work when I did not use two functions)</strike>

edit: I found the real cause to be that the function is not updating the time when it is called. It will always return the time when it was first loaded for some reason.

code below

```
var masterTimeUTC = new Date(); //these need to be global for the solveTime to work
    var utcHours = masterTimeUTC.getUTCHours();
    var utcMinutes = masterTimeUTC.getUTCMinutes();
    var utcSeconds = masterTimeUTC.getUTCSeconds();
    var utcMinutesLead = masterTimeUTC.getUTCMinutes();

function manualTime() {
    //the main show
    var masterTimeLocal = new Date(); //this contains everything, so we can mess with it more
    var localhours = masterTimeLocal.getHours();
    var localminutes = masterTimeLocal.getMinutes();
    var localseconds = masterTimeLocal.getSeconds();
    //get all the relvant info for this stuff
    if (localminutes < 10) {
        localminutes = "0" + localminutes;
    }
    if (localseconds < 10) {
        localseconds = "0" + localseconds;
    }
    if (localhours < 10) {
        localhours = "0" + localhours;
    } //make it look nice
    //solve times based on utc codes
    solveTime(0);//utc 0
    solveTime(-7); //west
    solveTime(-6); //mountain
    solveTime(-5); //central
    solveTime(-4); //east
    solveTime(1); //uk
    solveTime(8); //perth
    solveTime(9); //adelaide
    solveTime(10); //sydney
    //use the solveTime function to solve for times. syntax is x
    // x is the utc modifier, it can be any number incl. negatives
    document.getElementById("clocksingle").innerHTML = localhours + ":" + localminutes + "." + localseconds;
    //set the big time on top.
    setTimeout(manualTime, 1000);
    //run this every second to simulate a real clock
}


function solveAll() {
    manualTime();
    solveTime(-7);
    solveTime(-6);
    solveTime(-5);
    solveTime(-4);
    solveTime(0);
    solveTime(8);
    solveTime(9);
    solveTime(10);
}
//solveTime
//this will handle everything, including am, pm, printing to div, whatever
//the div name is whatever the utc modifier is
function solveTime(x) {
    if (x < 0) {
        var shift = 24 + x;
    } else {
        var shift = x;
    }

    var suffixSolve = (utcHours + shift) % 24;
    var suffix = "am";
    if (suffixSolve > 12) {
        suffix = "pm";
    }
    if (utcMinutes == 0) {
        utcMinutesLead = "00";
    }
    if (utcMinutes < 10) {
        utcMinutesLead = "0" + utcMinutes;
    }
    var timeSolve = (((utcHours + x) + 11) % 12 + 1);
    var timeTotal = timeSolve + ":" + utcMinutesLead + " " + suffix;
    var utcMod = x;
    if (utcMod > 0) {
        utcMod = "+" + utcMod;
    }
    if (x === 0){
        document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = timeTotal;
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = "(UTC" + utcMod + ") " + timeTotal;
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(1000);
    manualTime();

}

window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(60000);
    solveAll();
}
```

edit:

I added some console outputs to the solveTime function, it seems to be running every seconds (thanks to the setTimeout) but is not updating the time it is solving from. I tried adding a `new Date()` inside the function but that is not working either.

edit2:

this isn't a duplicate, the function is called fine. The times inside of the functions do not update whenever it is run again.

Comment: Post your code in your question, not a link to it on your site.

Comment: I added the code to the question

Comment: Shouldn't have been marked as a duplicate to 'Calling functions with setTimeout()', since the function that @mark really needs in this case would be `setInterval`.

Comment: I clarified my title and the linked problem is not the same as mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        manualTime();
    ),1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    setInterval(function(){
        solveAll();
    ),60000);
}
```

Comment: This does work actually, just not for the problem I have (Function not updating time, only uses the time it was when it is first loaded)

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout is an asynchronous operation, doesn't block execution like synchronous code.

```
setTimeout(1000);
manualTime(); // <-- this runs immediately after, not after 1000ms
```

The first argument to setTimeout is the callback function, and the time in milliseconds is the second argument. The callback function gets called ([at the minimum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971898/how-to-create-an-accurate-timer-in-javascript)) right after the time expires.

As you've done so at the end of `manualTime()`, you should pass the callback directly in the code within `window.onload` as well:

```
setTimeout(manualTime, 1000);
```

Same thing for `solveAll`.

Also you can put everything in a single `onload` handler, there's no need for the separation:

```
window.onload = function () {
  setTimeout(manualTime, 1000);
  setTimeout(solveAll, 60000);
}
```

Comment: This results in an `eval` and is not recommended.

Comment: @dperish what do you mean? There's no call to `eval` anywhere?

Comment: See this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058996/why-does-calling-settimeout-with-parenthesis-not-start-a-new-callstack.  or this:  http://e.epubbud.com/read.php?g=54B6SAEK&p=77

Comment: @dperish that still has nothing to do with `eval` ' and is also not what I'm doing in my answer. `eval` happens internally when you pass a string to `setTimeout` as the first argument. I'm passing a function. If my answer suggested `setTimeout(manualTime(), 1000)` (notice the `()`), then your argument might apply.

Comment: Sorry, didn't examine your whole post.  I stand corrected