# setTimeout within a for loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set a delay in the for loop in javascript. I want it to log `i`, have a delay, then log `i`, and so on. My question is, why does the following code **work**, having a function return a function as can be seen below:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        var tick = function(i) {
            return function() {
                console.log(i);
            }
        };
        setTimeout(tick(i), 500 * i);
    }
```

And the following code **not work** as expected:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var tick = function(i) {
        return console.log(i);

    };
    setTimeout(tick(i), 500 * i);
}
```

It prints out all the values in the for loop at once. Could someone please explain why this happens?

Comment: first argument to setTimeout needs to be a function, not the result of calling a function, unless, as in the first case, the result of calling a function is a function itself

Comment: switch `var` to `let`

Comment: @Endless - no difference, as the second code example will try to call `undefined` after the timeout

Comment: @Endless - I disagree about the duplicate - as the code fails in the second example due to the misunderstanding of setTimeout more than closures

Comment: The issue with the second code block is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8058996/5743988).

Comment: @JaromandaX Ssh, I wanted the question to be closed in order to reopen and win a hat. Oh, well, closing to the appropriate target.

Comment: Hat's have slowed SO down so much!!! I hate hats, but insist on wearing them :p

Comment: You need to understand closures and the way they work.

If you want to print 1 to 5 then you need to write 

    `for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
     (function(x) {
         setTimeout(function() { console.log(x); }, x * 1000 );
        })(i);
    }`

//prints 0 , 1 ,2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: `var tick = function(i) {
            return function() {
                console.log(i);
            }
       };`


`tick(i)` is the inner function returned, right?
This is called a **closure**, which keeps having its environment.


[`A closure is a function having access to the parent scope, even after the parent function has closed.`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp)


Thus each of the inner functions has a different value for _i_.
That's why the inner functions can log _i_ of the time when they're generated even though it is called later. + I upvoted. :)

Answer (score 3):

In both pieces of code, `tick(i)` is executed immediately in each loop

The difference is, that in the first example, tick(i) returns a function, which is called by setTimeout, and that outputs to the console

In the second example, the console.log is called immediately, undefined is returned, and setTimeout does nothing once the timeout has triggered as the given argument is not a function (or a string to be eval'd)