# Stop two sounds from playing at the same time

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a delay to the second sound, so it only plays after the first sound is finished playing. How can I do that? I've tried setTimeout, but it doesn't work.

```
 var notify = new Audio('resources/vox/notify.mp3');
 var hello = new Audio('resources/vox/hello.mp3');

 var commands = {
            'hi': function () {
            notify.load();
            notify.play();
            hello.load();
            setTimeout(hello.play(), 3000);
            $('#hello_r').show("slow");
        }
    };
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [why is this setTimeout not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116223/why-is-this-settimeout-not-working) and many, many others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
setTimeout(function() { hello.play(); }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an anonymous function wrapper in the callback of setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    hello.play();
}, 3000);
```

If you're rendering your audio file in an audio tag, you can also do:

```
<audio id="Notify" onended="playHello();"></audio>
```

Supposing `setTimeout` is a rather hack-y way to approach this. Refer to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_ended.asp) link for more info on `DOM ended` property.