# Why is the function executed immediately when I use setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm trying to write simple code with a `setTimeout`, but the `setTimeout` just won't wait the time it's supposed to and the code executes immediately. What am I doing wrong?

```
setTimeout(testfunction(), 2000);
```

Comment: `()` acts as an invocation operator here. But you want to pass the function to `setTimeout`, not invoke it.

Comment: Dup of [Why is my function call scheduled by setTimeout executed immediately?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037203/), [Calling functions with setTimeout()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800512/), [Javascript setTimeout() is ignoring the timeout length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120781/)

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You're calling the function immediately and scheduling its return value.

Use:

```
setTimeout(testFunction, 2000);
                       ^
```

Notice: no parens.

Comment: ok, thanks.. but is there a way to send paramters to the function like setTimeout(testFunction(obj),2000)??! by the way this won't work too setTimeout(alert("test"),2000)..

Comment: @Adler: Yes: `setTimeout(function() { alert("test"); }, 2000);`

Comment: @Adler: It's possible to do `setTimeout(alert, 2000, "test")` but it's not supported by IE.

Comment: @Adler: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback

Answer (score 32):

Remove the parenthesis

```
setTimeout(testfunction(), 2000);
```

If you want to send parameters to the function, you can create an anonymous function which will then call your desired function.

```
setTimeout(function() {

    testfunction('hello');

}, 2000);
```

**Edit**

Someone suggested to send a string as the first parameter of setTimeout. I would suggest not to follow this and never send a string as a setTimeout first parameter, cause the eval function will be used. This is bad practice and should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 9):

Remove the parentheses after the `testfunction` name:

```js
setTimeout(testfunction, 2000);
```

The reason is that the first argument to `setTimeout` should be a function *reference*, not the return value of the function. In your code, `testfunction` is called immediately and the return value is sent to `setTimeout`.

Comment: ok, thanks.. but is there a way to send paramters to the function like setTimeout(testFunction(obj),2000)??!  by the way this won't work too setTimeout(alert("test"),2000)...

Comment: @Adler yes, you can pass all your args after the delay argument, like this: `setTimeout(testFunction, 2000, obj)`

Answer (score 4):

I see a lot of answers here, but I just want to take some time to explain the root cause of the problem.

Actually setTimeOut() function is an asynchronous function and when you pass a function as one of the parameter to the setTimeOut() function, your script actually does not want to waste your time and wants to execute your passed function as soon as possible.

So there are few ways in which you can bypass this. You can either use callbacks or promises.

Refer to this link for quick detail: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp

I will show you how can you use callback to achieve what you want to achieve.

By doing -

```
setTimeOut(your_function_name_without_parentheses, <number of milliseconds>)
```

You can actually tell your timeout that please execute yourself first and then execute my callback function passed as the first parameter.

Or if you want to pass a parameter to the callback function, you can do something like this -

```
setTimeOut(() => {your_function_name_with_parentheses(argument_that_you_want_to_pass), <number of milliseconds>})
```

There are other ways as well which are already answered above.

Also, I am a newbie to JS, please let me know if there are any gaps in my understanding.

Answer (score 3):

First remove the parenthesis:

```
setTimeout(testfunction, 2000);
```

And then, if you want to pass parameters in `setTimeout` function, you can pass in this way:

```
 setTimeout(testfunction, 2000, param1, param2);
```

**Note:** You can pass multiple parameters according to your function requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Well you might have got the answer but I am explaining the cause and solution.  There are two ways in which you can call a function after required amount of time.
1. setTimeout("FUNC_NAME ()', TIME_IN_MS);
   Here FUNC_NAME inside double quotes is the original function you want to call after TIME_IN_MS milliseconds.  This is because if you do not put the quotes then while java script is getting interpreted the function would be immediately executed and your purpose would get defeated.  To let interpreter skip the statement we need to put quotes here.
2. setTimeout(function () {FUNC_NAME ()}, TIME_IN_MS);
   Here anonymous function is created that tells interpreter to execute if after certain time instead of evaluating time.

Thanks
shaILU

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parenthesis, currently you are invoking the function immediately. What is currently being passed to setTimeout is the returned value from the testfunction() call, but what you should pass to setTimeout as the first argument is a function reference

```
setTimeout(testfunction, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, but please explain how this adds anything to the existing answers that have been around for a decade.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone experiencing issues not related to calling the function immediately **and using Node.js**, your timeout value may be too large causing the delay to default 1.

e.g. `setTimeout(testFunction, 21474836471) == setTimeout(testFunction, 1)`

[When delay is larger than 2147483647 or less than 1, the delay will be set to 1. Non-integer delays are truncated to an integer.](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_class_timeout)

Comment: That's only true for nodejs

Comment: I had the same issue with the delay set around 2500000000 milliseconds (about 29 days)