# Why is my function invoked before the timeout of setTimeout() occurs?

Tags: javascript, firefox, settimeout

This doesn't seem right, but this is how Firefox appears to be acting.

```
setTimeout(print(),5000);
function print(){
    console.log(1);
}
```

Before the 5 seconds are up, after a link is clicked and before the next page begins to render, 1 is printed to the console. Any ideas? Thanks!

**Edit**: retitled, to make it obvious that there is a bug in the example code, not in firefox behavior.

Comment: For what it's  worth, 50000 milliseconds is 50 seconds, not 5.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the method executed immediately when I use setTimeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137401/why-is-the-method-executed-immediately-when-i-use-settimeout)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the problem is that you are executing the print function immediately. Remove the brackets so you pass the function object rather than execute it.

```
setTimeout(print,50000);
```

Answer (score 4):

Firefox will call `print` when it gets an expression that calls it, such as `print()`.

You are calling `print` and passing its return value (`undefined`) to `setTimeout`.

Drop the `()` to pass the function itself.