# Why does the following setTimeout print straight away?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following prints my message straight away

```
setTimeout(console.log('delayed hello world'), 10000);
```

It's a little bit counterintuitive.  And since my message print straight away what happens at the end of 10 seconds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the method executed immediately when I use setTimeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137401/why-is-the-method-executed-immediately-when-i-use-settimeout) and [so many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=why+does+settimeout+execute+the+function+immediately).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use anonymously function for that:

```
setTimeout(function() { console.log('delayed hello world') }, 10000);
```

See more about passing params to `setTimeout` function at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)

Answer (score 4):

You are running console.log (because you have `()` on the end of it) and passing its return value to `setTimeout` instead of passing a function.

```
var myFunction = function () { console.log('delayed hello world'); }
setTimeout(myFunction, 10000);
```