# setTimeout not working for delay

Tags: jquery, fancybox, settimeout, delay

I have a user defined function i want to delay it's execution. want to
 delay fancy() and I am using setTimeout. But it runs instantaneously.I have also set different time delays
 but it does not effect.Is there any other method or I am using it wrong?? please help.

Thanks in advance.
Ali

```
$('a.vid').click(function(){


        setTimeout(fancy(this) ,2000 );


});



function fancy(that){

            var videoFile = $(that).attr('videofile');
            var videoWidth = Number($(that).attr('videowidth'));
            var videoHeight =Number( $(that).attr('videoheight'));

            var videoCode = '<video width="'+videoWidth+'" height="'+videoHeight+'" controls autoplay autobuffer><source src="includes/video/'+videoFile+'.ogv" type="video/ogg" /><source src="includes/video/'+videoFile+'.mp4" type="video/mp4" /><object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="'+videoWidth+'" height="'+(videoHeight+40)+'" id="lynda_video_player" align="middle"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="movie" value="lynda_video_player.swf?videoFile=includes/video/'+videoFile+'.mp4&amp;skinFile=lynda_video_skin.swf&amp;videoFileWidth='+videoWidth+'&amp;videoFileHeight='+videoHeight+'"><param name="quality" value="high"><param name="wmode" value="transparent"><param name="scale" value="noscale"><param name="salign" value="lt"><embed src="lynda_video_player.swf?videoFile=includes/video/'+videoFile+'.mp4&amp;skinFile=lynda_video_skin.swf&amp;videoFileWidth='+videoWidth+'&amp;videoFileHeight='+videoHeight+'" quality="high" width="'+videoWidth+'" height="'+(videoHeight+40)+'" name="lynda_video_player" align="middle" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" scale="noscale" salign="lt" wmode="transparent" allowfullscreen="true" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></embed></object></video>';


            $('#videoPlayer').html(videoCode);

            $.fancybox({

                'transitionIn' : 'fade',
                'transitionOut' : 'fade',
                'overlayColor' : '#000',
                'overlayOpacity' : '.6',
                'href' : '#videoPlayer'


                });

    }
```

Comment: +1 welcome to our community! 2 questions within 2 hrs  to our community!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the method executed immediately when I use setTimeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137401/why-is-the-method-executed-immediately-when-i-use-settimeout)

Comment: What do you want to do : to show a video after some seconds  on page load? Could you show your html code too? I think you are making things way more complicated than they should.

Answer (score 7):

use

```
setTimeout(function() {
fancy(this);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Delay worked but fancybox couldn't catch video which was working before delay.

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass an anonymous function to setTimeout, so the correct form is:

```
setTimeout(function() {fancy(this)}, delay);
```

**Way to Way**

if you have a function **delayfunction()** (with out parameter) following is ok

```
setTimeout(delayfunction, delay); //note  no `()`
```

If you want to send parameters to the function, you will have to call an anonymous function which will then call your desired function.

```
setTimeout(function() {

    delayfunction('parms');

}, 2000);
```

Duplicate : [Why is the method executed immediately when I use setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137401/why-is-the-method-executed-immediately-when-i-use-settimeout)

Comment: delay worked. Popup box of fancybox opens after delay time but with no video. i have also tried setTimeout(function() {

    // function body

}, 2000);  with $(this) instead of $(that).