# Nodejs promises, launches function before previous one finished

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

maybe i am not understanding promises, why am i getting redirected before functions.dioNic ends?

```
app.get('/dionic/scan', function(req, res) {
var functions = require("./functions.js");
var scrape = require("./scrapers/dionic.js");
//render index.ejs file
scrape.scrapeDio
// Remove duplicates in array data
.then(dedupe)
// Save
.then(functions.dioNic)
.then(console.log("Guardado"))
.then(res.redirect('/'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling these functions and passing their return values to `then` instead of passing the functions themselves:

```
.then(console.log("Guardado"))
.then(res.redirect('/'));
```

This is effectively the same problem [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7137401/772035).

You can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to get a function with the argument bound:

```
.then(console.log.bind(console, "Guardado"))
.then(res.redirect.bind(res, '/'));
```

You could also use anonymous functions, if you don't like the look of bind:

```
.then( function () { console.log("Guardado") })
.then( function () { res.redirect('/') });
```