# Calculating modulos using JavaScript returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I wrote a function to calculate the modulus of a function but when I run it in the console it always returns undefined. If I use the console.log I can see that it is calculating the correct value.

```js
function modulo(sum, divider){ 
  function loop(difference){ 
    if(difference < divider){ 
     console.log(difference)
     return difference
    } else { 
       setTimeout(loop(difference - divider), 0)
    } 
  } 
  
  return loop(sum - divider) 
}

modulo(8, 5) // 3
```

what I want is this to return the answer 
e.g.

`var result = modulo(8, 5) // 3`

Update:

A better solution to this problem would be

`modulo = function (x,y){ return x - y * Math.floor(x/y) }`

Comment: Note: `setTimeout()`, if used correctly, would make the `function` asynchronous / event-driven and unable to `return` under current standards. See "[Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)" And, for why I say "*if used correctly*," see "[Why is the method executed immediately when I use setTimeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137401/why-is-the-method-executed-immediately-when-i-use-settimeout)"

Comment: Thanks for the comments Jonathan :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your original question, `setTimeout` is asynchronous, and your `loop` function returns undefined, hence you get undefined. To make it do what you want, call `loop` directly, or use promises.

But on the other hand, even if you were to implement modulus, this is a poor approach. Use some better [division algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm) instead.

Comment: Do you mean this gcd formula? `function gcd(a, b)
    if b = 0
       return a
    else
       return gcd(b, a mod b)` Could you please explain further?

Comment: Ah! Got it -`mod = function (x,y){ return x - y * Math.floor(x/y) }`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to create a new function for this, JavaScript already has it's own modulus operator: `%`.

```
8 % 5
-> 3
```

If you really want to turn this into a function, you can simply:

```
function modulo(sum, divider) {
    return sum % divider;
}
```

```js
modulo(8, 5);
-> 3
```

Comment: Thanks James, you are right, but I was doing this as a coding exercise

Answer (score 0):

Because your code does not return value from the loop.

Try this:

```js
function modulo(sum, divider) {
  function loop(difference) {
    if (difference < divider) {
      return difference;
    } else {
      return loop(difference - divider);
    }
  }

  return loop(sum - divider);
}

alert(modulo(8, 5));
```