# Passing a function reference as a callback function

Tags: javascript, function, callback, lodash

How do I used a function I defined somewhere as a callback function. I am trying to pass a named function to lodash:

```
function boo(value, key) {
  // do something
}

_.forOwn(object, boo(value, key));
```

This doesn't work, I get `value is not defined`. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Put the console.log(value) before _.forOwn(object, boo(value, key))

Comment: Ignore the title of the duplicate, the answer is the same.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137401/why-is-the-method-executed-immediately-when-i-use-settimeout?lq=1 and many many other duplicates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, you are invoking the function, not passing a ref `boo(value, key)`

To pass a ref to the function, just type the name of the function as an argument
`_.forOwn(object, boo);`