# jQuery.remove() and setTimeout interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function that creates an element when the user hovers on a element. When the mouse goes away from the element I set a timeout to destroy it. While creating and normally destroying the element does work flawlessly, the `remove` inside the timeout does not work and dies silently. I suspect there is some problem in the interaction between `window.setTimeout` and `jQuery.remove`, but couldn't find anything on the web.

My code:

```
//Element creation
function createElement(){
    $(".my_class").remove()
    content = compose_content() //It's an <ul>
    $('<div></div>', {
        class : "my_class",
        html: content
     }).insertAfter($("#first_row"))
}

//Element destruction
function setDestroyTimeout(){
    if(perform_some_checks()){
         window.setTimeout(function(){
              console.log("Removing...")
              $(".my_class").remove()
         }, 1000)
    }
}

$(".another_class").hover(createElement(), setDestroyTimeout())
```

The first remove (the one in the `createElement` function) works smoothly, while the second doesn't do anything. The Timeout works as well, I checked with the `console.log` instruction.

Comment: Call vs reference `$(".another_class").hover(createElement(), setDestroyTimeout())` ==> `$(".another_class").hover(createElement, setDestroyTimeout)`

Comment: Could you please expand it? It's somewhat unclear

Comment: The `()` in `setDestroyTimeout()` calls the function `setDestroyTimeout`. The result of that function call (in your case `undefined`) is then passed as callback to your `hover`. Look at this related question: [Why is the method executed immediately when I use setTimeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137401)

Comment: The element is probably not created yet when you set the second destroy, the jquery try to remove, but the element is not add yet.

Comment: The problem was the one @t.niese (and I also suspect @Tushar) pointed out. Thanks!