# How to define a callback function and trigger it later?

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I have a problem with callbacks. I'm using semantic and i want a callback to be fired to do something on response (onResponse).

**I can make it this way and it works:**

```
var drop = $('.ui.dropdown');
drop.dropdown();
drop.api({
    action: 'someAction',
    on: 'now',
    onResponse: funcion(response){
        //do some operations using the response variables AFTER the server    
    }
});
```

**But i want to do it this other way:**

```
var drop = $('.ui.dropdown');
drop.dropdown();
drop.api({
    action: 'someAction',
    on: 'now',
    onResponse: func(response)
});

function func(response) {
    //do some operations using the response variables AFTER the server responses
}
```

As you may have noticed, **the second way is erroneous** because the function is doing it's operations before the response variable get's fulfilled.

### Is there a way to do this correctly?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but still the same reason: [Why is the method executed immediately when I use setTimeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137401), `func(...)` will call the function `func`. Without the braces you pass/store store the function object itself for later usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling function with this:
`func(response)` you should use only `func`. So, please try:

```
drop.api({
    action: 'someAction',
    on: 'now',
    onResponse: func
});
```

Comment: Because when you don't pass argument the `func` is a pointer to that function. When you pass argument, you are executing this function right now.

Comment: @Hernan, because you do not call the function at that point, you just want to store your function in the `onResponse` property, so that the  `drop.api` can later call that stored function, and at that point the argument will be passed by the code of `drop.api`.