# setTimeout seems to be executing instantly

Tags: javascript, recursion, settimeout

I am trying to teach myself some JavaScript and play around with recursion at the same time. The code I've written below I expect to print "inhale" to the console 10 times with a 5-second delay in between printing. However when I watch the console in Chrome's dev tools, all entries get printed seemingly instantaneously after refreshing the page. Can anyone help me find the error in my implementation? Thank you!

```
function breathe(type, counter, limit, duration) {
  if(counter <= limit) {
    setTimeout(console.log(type), duration);
    counter++;

    return breathe(type, counter, limit, duration);
  }

  console.log("Finished!");
}

var breathing = breathe("inhale", 1, 10, 5000);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the method executed immediately when I use setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137401/why-is-the-method-executed-immediately-when-i-use-settimeout)

Answer (score 2):

The `setTimeout` method expects a function ref. This should work.

```
function breathe(type, counter, limit, duration) {
  if(counter <= limit) {
    setTimeout(function(){console.log(type)}, duration);
    counter++;

    return breathe(type, counter, limit, duration);
  }

  console.log("Finished!");
}

var breathing = breathe("inhale", 1, 10, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are executing your `console` statement immediately (since you are executing `console.log` via the `()`), rather than passing in a function reference to `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(console.log(type), duration);
```

Try this instead:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(type)
}, duration);
```

Another form you could use (just to hammer-home the concept of passing a function reference) is this:

```
function callMeAfterDelay() {
    console.log(type);
}

setTimeout(callMeAfterDelay, duration);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(console.log(type), duration);
```

This is immediately executing `console.log(type)`, and then passing the result into setTimeout. The result of console.log is `undefined`, so nothing happens when the timeout goes off.

Instead, you want to do this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(type);
}, duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
function breathe(type, counter, limit, duration) {
  if(counter <= limit) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(type);
        counter++;

        return breathe(type, counter, limit, duration);
    }, duration);
  }

  console.log("Finished!");
}

var breathing = breathe("inhale", 1, 10, 5000);
```

Comment: Stack Overflow answers should be more than just working code. They should explain what the problem was and how the solution solves it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var counter = 0;

var duration = 2000

var text = "Inhale";

var limit = 10;

function print(counter, duration, text, limit) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(text, counter)
    counter++;
    if (counter < limit) {
      print(counter, duration, text, limit);
    }
  },duration)
};

print(counter, duration, text, limit);
```

Try this.