# setTimeout does not work inside forEach loop in Typescript / Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have `forEach` loop that hides an HTML element after 10 sec. I've put it inside a `setTimeout` function but it's not waiting for 10 sec, the element is hiding with page load.
Not sure if it is because of Angulars lifecycle looks or `forEach` loop.

Here is my typescript code

```js
ngAfterViewChecked() {  
    if(this.on) {  
      this._notificationsElements.forEach((element) => {      
        const htmlElement = element.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
        setTimeout(htmlElement.setAttribute("style", "display:none;"), 10000);
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the method executed immediately when I use setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137401/why-is-the-method-executed-immediately-when-i-use-settimeout)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setTimeout(htmlElement.setAttribute("style", "display:none;"),10000);
```

needs to be:

```
setTimeout(() => htmlElement.setAttribute("style", "display:none;"),10000);
```

setTimeout requires a function.

Comment: That being said, hiding it like this is a pretty dirty way of doing it.