# JS setTimeout Not Delayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I'm trying to put a delay in **front** of an `AJAX` call.

```
var delay = 2000;

$("#c_name").on("keyup", function() {
  var entered = $(this).val();
  if (entered.length > 1) { 
    setTimeout(dosearch(entered), delay) 
    }
  });
```

Fo some reason I can't seem to get `setTimeout` to take hold.  It's performing the `dosearch()` function instantly.

How can I get this to delay properly?  Yes `JQuery 3.3.1` is loaded up top.

Comment: because you call it and assign what it returns to the timeout....

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate.  Read the answer to that question.  "No parentheses" is not the answer.

Comment: You can either wrap the function or add the parameters after the `delay` parameter:  `setTimeout(dosearch, delay, entered)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Parameters

Comment: `dosearch(entered)` is a function call. It is evaluated *before* `setTimeout()` is invoked.

Comment: I'm under the impression that `dosearch(entered)` is performed after.  How can I delay that using `setTimeout(function, delay)`?

Comment: it will execute the return value of the `dosearch(entered)`

Comment: Again, read all the answers to the duplicate.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7137443/1586174

Comment: `setTimeout(() => dosearch(entered), delay) `

Comment: Yes, that's what I want.  AFTER the delay.

Comment: Wrap `dosearch(entered)` in a function: `function() { dosearch(entered); }`

Answer (score -1):

Answer:  Both of these work:

```
setTimeout(() => dosearch(entered), delay) 

setTimeout( function() { dosearch(entered) }, delay)
```