# How to show an error log on .click() by using the .show() and .hide() methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show, bootstrap-tabs

I created a page where the user is asked to do a search query by inserting a name, an address or a phone number, which correspond to three navigation tabs ("Name", "Address" and "Number") and each of them is associated to an input text form and a "Search" button.

What I want to do now is *displaying an **error log** whenever the user **clicks on the "Search" button** without having filled the corresponding field*. For example, if the user is on the "Name" Tab and clicks on the "Search" button, an error message saying "Please insert a name" is displayed.

I included the error message in a `<p>` tag in the html file and I want to use the JQuery `.show()` and `.hide()` methods to show such a message only when the two conditions below occur simultaneously:
1) the field is empty;
2) the button is clicked.
Otherwise, the message is hidden.

Here is my Javascript snippet, it doesn't work for my purpose:

```
    function validateName(){
        if($("#inlineFormInputName").val()==""){
            $("#searchNome").on('click', $("#errorLog").show());
        } 
    }
    function validateAddress(){
        if($("#inlineFormInputAddress").val()==""){
            $("#searchAddress").on('click', $("#errorLog").show());
        }
    }
    function validatePhone(){       
        if($("#inlineFormInputTelefono").val()==""){
            $("#searchPhone").on('click', $("#errorLog").show());
        }
    }
    function main(){
        $("#searchNome").on('click', validateName);
        $("#searchAddress").on('click', validateAddress);
        $("#searchPhone").on('click', validatePhone);
    }

    $(main());
```

The #ID correspond respectively:

- *inlineFormInputName* = id of the input form - first Tab;
- *searchName* = button ID - firs Tab;
- *errorLog* = id of the `<p>` containing the error message
- *inlineFormInputAddress* = id of the input form corresponding to the 2ndTab;
- *searchAddress* = button ID - 2nd Tab;
- *inlineFormInputTelefono* = id of the input form corresponding to the 3rd Tab;
- *searchPhone* = button ID - 3rd Tab.

I upload a screen of the webpage:

[image]

How may I show an error message only if the two conditions are satisfied, by using the JQuery `.show()` and `.hide()` methods?

Comment: Callbacks are expected to be function definitions/references.  `$(...).show()` is not a function definition.  It is a function execution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the method executed immediately when I use setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137401/why-is-the-method-executed-immediately-when-i-use-settimeout)

Comment: The duplicate is for timeouts, but both timeouts and event bindings use callbacks.  The same error is present there and here.

Answer (score 0):

If with minimal changes in your code...

The used thing is called 'Ternary Operator':

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/3qvrfset/)

```js
function validateName(){
  ( $("#inlineFormInputName").val().length == 0 ) ? $("#errorLog").show() : $("#errorLog").hide();
}
function validateAddress(){
  ( $("#inlineFormInputAddress").val().length == 0 ) ? $("#errorLog").show() : $("#errorLog").hide();
}
function validatePhone(){
  ( $("#inlineFormInputTelefono").val().length == 0 ) ? $("#errorLog").show() : $("#errorLog").hide();
}

function main(){
  $("#searchNome").on('click', validateName);
  $("#searchAddress").on('click', validateAddress);
  $("#searchPhone").on('click', validatePhone);
}

(main)();
```

```css
#errorLog {display: none; color: red; margin: 10px;}
```

```html
<input id="inlineFormInputName">
<button id="searchNome">search</button>
  <br><br>
<input id="inlineFormInputAddress">
<button id="searchAddress">search</button>
  <br><br>
<input id="inlineFormInputTelefono">
<button id="searchPhone">search</button>

<div id="errorLog">bubu!</div>
```

P.s. Be careful with your inlineFormInput`Telefono` and search`Phone`... can be messed somewhere...