# How to check if image is clicked after creating it through JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an image in js after clicking on a button. How do I perform an action on the image when it is clicked *after* it has been rendered? Here is the code I tried:

```
function sayhi(){

    for (var m = 0; m <animals.length;m++){
        var image = document.createElement('img');
        image.src = "animalgameback.jpg";
        image.id = animals[m];
        document.getElementById('body').appendChild(image); 
        image.onclick = flip(this);

    }
}
```

However when I set the onclick image attribute, it performs the task only before the image has even been rendered. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the method executed immediately when I use setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137401/why-is-the-method-executed-immediately-when-i-use-settimeout)

Comment: Basically, you're setting `onclick` to the result of calling `flip(this)`. You should consider using the more modern [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method of adding event listeners rather than the old style on* properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change the line:

```
image.onclick = flip(this);
```

to this:

```
image.addEventListener("click",function flip(this){ }, this);
```

Comment: Use markdown to format code snippets. [Details here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

event handlers have to be a function, so :::

change this

```
image.onclick = flip(this);
```

to this

```
image.onclick = function(){flip(image);}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
image.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  flip(this) 
}, false)
```

Remember to not use arrow functions if you want to access `this` scope of a function.

Answer (score 0):

You're not binding the function flip here to the 'click' event, but the result, or return value of the call to a function identified as flip.
The this value added to the call might be window.

```
image.onclick = flip;
```

and a function like the following:

```
function flip (event) {
  var
    eImage = event.target;
  ...

  ...
}
```

might be a quick solution.