# addEventListener return null when clicked

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

When I clicked on the button I want it to go to previous page but when its clicked it returns null.

```
const button = document.querySelector('.btn__back');
button.addEventListener('click', movieView.goBack());
```

This is my go back function.

```
export const goBack = () => {
window.history.back();
```

}

I have added an if statement to check the element exist before attaching the event but now it doesnt do anything when function is invoked.

```
const button = document.querySelector('.btn__back');
if (button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => movieView.goBack());

}
```

I found the solution to the problem. I found the solution I had to attach the eventlistener to the container because I can’t select the button by the time this code runs because its not on the page.

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137401/why-is-the-method-executed-immediately-when-i-use-settimeout

Comment: Why not just do it as an anchor tag?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `button` is `null` - double-check that the selector that you're using is correct.
2. `addEventListener` expects a callback function. You need this:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.btn__back');
button.addEventListener('click', () => movieView.goBack());
```

otherwise, the `movieView.goBack()` will just get called once and return null, and then the `addEventListener`, once an event happens, will try to call `null` instead of `movieView.goBack`.

MDN has great documentation for things like this -- see https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: While this is true, that isn't what the question is asking about

Comment: What do you mean? The question is, quote "When I clicked on the button I want it to go to previous page but when its clicked it returns null". This happens precisely because the event listener expects a `() => fn()` instead of `fn()`.

Comment: The question is asking why `button` is `null`. That has nothing to do with what arguments are passed to `addEventListener`.

Comment: Oh wait correct - that's the first problem. I only mentioned the second one -- updated.

Comment: It would be better if the question were just closed as a duplicate. These are FAQS. They don't need new answers.

Comment: I do indeed agree.

Comment: it still returns null.