# Issue with setTimeout in repeating a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function that will repeat itself every x seconds, but I'm not sure it's repeating.
My code:

```js
function myfunction() {
  if (nonimportant) {
    do something;
  }
  else {
    do something else;
  }
  setTimeout(myfunction(),1000);
}
```

Comment: [Why is the method executed immediately when I use setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7137401)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Any particular reason you didn't vote to close as a duplicate?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Well, it wasn't _exactly_ the same. Your dup is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the perfect use case for [.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals)(*Scroll down to the setIntervall() part below setTimeout()*)

```js
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  console.log(t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the () out:

```
function myfunction() {
  if (nonimportant) {
    do something;
  }
  else {
    do something else;
  }
  setTimeout(myfunction,1000);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Answer (score -1):

Typical error: you pass the result of the function instead of the function itself to the `setTimeout`:

```
function myfunction() {
  if (nonimportant) {
    do something;
  }
  else {
    do something else;
  }
  setTimeout(myfunction,1000);  //notice there's no brackets
}
```

Comment: "Typical error:" Answering a duplicate. Instead, vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I agree that it can be a duplicate, but why only my answer was downvoted?

Comment: You have enough rep to vote to close. The other person with enough rep suggested a different approach, which is fine, although still makes it harder to delete the question.

Comment: what? different approach??? the code is exactly the same: check all the answers!

Comment: I did. Apparently *you're* missing the difference between `setInterval` and `setTimeout`. But I'm done. You got one downvote which reduced your number of imaginary internet points by an infinitesimal amount. Learn the lesson or don't.