# How can I simplify my javascript and ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a couple of buttons for a demo application

```
<div style="margin-top: 10px;" class="text-center">
    <h3>Events</h3>
    <button id="trackTrace" class="btn btn-warning">TrackTrace()</button>
    <button id="trackException" class="btn btn-warning">TrackException()</button>
    <button id="trackEvent" class="btn btn-warning">TrackEvent()</button>
</div>
```

Now I would like to issue AJAX calls when one of the buttons is clicked. I solved this as follows.

```
<script>
    $("#trackTrace").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/event/trace",
            type: "GET",
            success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                $("#message").text("Success").show();
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                $("#error").text("Error").show();
            }
        })
    });

    ... 
</script>
```

This however seems to break the DRY principle, I don't want to repeat that for every button. Sure I could move the displaying of the text into a separate function.

However, the following calls `showError()` and `showSuccess()` even if the AJAX call was fine.

```
function showSucess(result, status, xhr) {
    $("#message").text("Success").show();
};

function showError(xhr, status, error) {
    $("#error").text("Exception thrown on Backend-API!").show();
};

$("#trackTrace").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/event/trace",
        type: "GET",
        success: showSucess(),
        error: showError()
    })
});
```

So how can I simplify my code? I am looking for a `switch` like way that acts upon button clicks.

Comment: Do  "success: showSucess, error: showError" without the parentheses. You want a function "pointer", not to call it immediately.

Comment: _"However, the following calls `showError()` and `showSuccess()` even if the AJAX call was fine"_ - This has nothing to do with the title. Calling a function is not the same as using a function as object. -> (Possible dupe) [Why is the method executed immediately when I use setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137401/why-is-the-method-executed-immediately-when-i-use-settimeout)

Comment: _"I am looking for a switch like way that acts upon button clicks."_ - Why a `switch`?

Answer (score 1):

1. Event handlers need to not have the () when used in an assignment
   `success: showSuccess,` - OR it has to return a function
2. Delegation is built into JS and jQuery

```js
$("#eventContainer .track").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/event/" + this.dataset.url,
        type: "GET",
        success: showSucess,
        error: showError
    })
})
```

```html
<div id="eventContainer" style="margin-top: 10px;" class="text-center">
    <h3>Events</h3>
    <button id="trackTrace" class="track btn btn-warning" data-url="tracktrace">TrackTrace()</button>
    <button id="trackException" class="track btn btn-warning" data-url="trackexception">TrackException()</button>
    <button id="trackEvent" class="track btn btn-warning" data-url="trackevent">TrackEvent()</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div style="margin-top: 10px;" class="text-center">
    <h3>Events</h3>
    <button data-url="/api/event/trace" class="btn btn-warning">TrackTrace()</button>
    <button data-url="/api/event/exception" class="btn btn-warning">TrackException()</button>
    <button data-url="/api/event/event" class="btn btn-warning">TrackEvent()</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("button[data-url]").each(function () {
    const clickedElement = this;
    $(this).click(function () {
      $.ajax({
          url: clickedElement.dataset.url,
          type: "GET",
          success: function (result, status, xhr) {
              $("#message").text("Success").show();
          },
          error: function (xhr, status, error) {
              $("#error").text("Error").show();
          }
      })
  });
});
```

Note that you don't need to assign `id` to your buttons. Also I'm not 100% sure syntax is correct as I haven't worked with jQuery for a while