# Need to wait for Google API but sleep function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, settimeout, svelte

I need to load Google Maps API in my svelte project.
I'm using js-api-loader npm package.

Here's the peace of code that I use to load the Google API:

**loader.js**

```js
import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader';

let googleIsLoaded = false;

async function loadGoogleMapsAPI() { 
  if (!googleIsLoaded) {
    const libraries = ['places'];
    try {
      const loader = new Loader({
        apiKey: API_KEY,
        version: 'weekly',
        libraries,
      });
      console.info('Loading Google API ...'); // LOGGED 1st -> OK
      await loader.load();
      console.info('Google API is loaded'); // LOGGED 6th -> KO
      googleIsLoaded = true;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(`Google API Loader failed ${error.message}`);
    }
  }
}
```

When a page loads, it first hits the route defined below
**route/index.svelte**:

```js
<script context="module">
  export const ssr = false;
</script>

<script>
  import MyComp from '$components/MyComp.svelte';
  import { loadGoogleMapsAPI } from '$lib/loader.js';

  init();

  async function init() {
    try {
      await loadGoogleMapsAPI();
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }

  <MyComp />
```

Then, **MyComp.svelte** below is loaded:

```js
import { onMount } from 'svelte';

let google;
onMount(() => {
    console.log('mounted'); // LOGGED 2nd -> OK
    google = window.google;
    if (google === undefined) {
      console.log('google is undefined'); // LOGGED 3rd -> OK
      sleep(5000, init());
    } else {
      console.log('google is defined');
    }
});

async function init() {
    ...
    autocompleteWidget = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options); 
/////////// LOGGED 5th -> KO: EXCEPTION GOOGLE IS NOT DEFINED /////////
}
```

and here the helper function to make the sleep

**helpers.js**

```js
export async function sleep(time, fn, ...args) {
  console.info('sleep ' + time + 'ms');  // LOGGED 4th -> OK
  await timeout(time);
  console.info('woken'); // LOGGED 7th -> KO
  return fn(...args);
}

function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

But for whatever reason, the init() function is triggered ignoring the `sleep(5000, init())` call :/

Thank you for your help.

**console**

```
loader.js: Loading Google API ...
MyComp.svelte: mounted
MyComp.svelte: google is undefined
helpers.js: sleep 5000ms
MyComp.svelte:106 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')
helpers.js: Google API is loaded
helpers.js: woken
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Why is the method executed immediately when I use setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137401/why-is-the-method-executed-immediately-when-i-use-settimeout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the function reference instead of calling it.

Change

```
sleep(5000, init());
```

to:

```
sleep(5000, init);
```