# Using setTimeout function not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

am trying to use the setTimeout function if the user clicks on the button, I want it to display successfully for just 3sec, it displaying but it's not executing the 3sec time given. what am I doing wrong?

Here’s my code

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState('')

  function handleSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault()

      emailjs.sendForm(process.env.SERVICE_ID,process.env.TEMPLATE_ID, form.current,process.env.PUBLIC_KEY)
    .then(function(response) {
     return setTimeout(setMessage("successFully sent"), 3000)
    }, function(err) {
      console.log('FAILED...', err);
    });
  }
```

Comment: That's not how setTimeout works. You're telling it to call setMessage 3 seconds after a successful response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the method executed immediately when I use setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137401/why-is-the-method-executed-immediately-when-i-use-settimeout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout(func,n)` executes `func` **after** `n` milliseconds.

If you want the message to be displayed **during** 3s,

1. Set the message *immediately*
2. Clear the message *after* 3s.

Inside your `then` callback,

```
setMessage('successfully sent'); 
setTimeout(()=>{ // may start timer before message is set.
    setMessage('')
}, 3000);
```

However due the asynchronous nature of state updates, the setTimeout may be "set" before the success message, resulting in the message for being shown for, example 2.993 seconds.

A more precise solution would be:

```
handleSubmit=(evt)=> { // arrow functions preserve 'this' of component
    // ....
    .then((response)=> {
         this.setState({message: 'Successfully sent'}, ()=> {
             setTimeout(()=> { // start timer after the message is set
                 this.setState({message: ''}); 
             }, 3000);
         }); 
    })
    // ...
}
```

Here the 2nd callback argument of `setState` is run, after message is set.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a anonymous function because right now you're calling the function when using setTimeout

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState('')

  function handleSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault()

      emailjs.sendForm(process.env.SERVICE_ID,process.env.TEMPLATE_ID, form.current,process.env.PUBLIC_KEY)
    .then(function(response) {
     return setTimeout(() => setMessage("successFully sent"), 3000)
    }, function(err) {
      console.log('FAILED...', err);
    });
  }
```

Comment: tried it, but still having same issue