# items saved and get by localstorage as well, but will disappear on page refresh

Tags: javascript

i have an array named todoList, all of my data is in it.
i saved them to localstorage like this:
https://codepen.io/arashkazerouni/pen/YzLxdoQ

```
const saveToLocal = (array) => {
  window.localStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify(array));
};

todoList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("todo"));
```

i used this saveToLocal function after any change in todoList, and it works.
the only problem is when i refresh the page, all items gone.
but if i add new todo, all of them will shown again

and there is page script :

```
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const todos = document.querySelector(".todos");
const alertRed = document.querySelector(".alert-red");

let todoList = [];
const saveToLocal = (array) => {
  window.localStorage.setItem("todo", JSON.stringify(array));
};

todoList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("todo"));
const addToDOM = () => {
  // todos.innerHTML = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < todoList.length; i++) {
    const html = `
    <div class="todo" id=${i}>
    <p class="todo-text" >${todoList[i]}</p>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-check" ></i>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>
    </div>
    `;
    todos.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
  }
};
// Add items to list
button.onclick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // todos.innerHTML = "";
  if (!todoList.includes(input.value) && input.value !== "") {
    todoList.push(input.value);
    saveToLocal(todoList);
  }
  // console.log(todoList);
  addToDOM();
  input.value = "";
};
// Handle Enter Press
document.onkeypress = (e) => {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    button.click();
  }
};
todos.onclick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const isCheck = e.target.classList.contains("fa-check");
  const isTrash = e.target.classList.contains("fa-trash");
  if (isCheck) e.target.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle("checked");
  if (isTrash) {
    const element = e.target.parentElement;
    const elementID = parseInt(element.id);
    element.classList.add("removed");
    todoList = todoList.filter((element) => element !== todoList[elementID]);
    saveToLocal(todoList);
    setTimeout(() => {
      addToDOM();
    }, 300);
  }
};
```

Comment: you can make sure that you dont call it anywhere with empty array?
can you please show me your page's script

Comment: `saveToLocal` function seems to be all good. However, why don't you initialize `todoList` with `const` or `let` ? Because this lines also look to be good, but the fact that you don't use any of those let us thing you are doing manipulation on it before, and this seems to be from where your problem come from. Please share a reproduction or more code as @islemdev asked

Comment: @ArashKazerooni it would be way easier and faster if you could share the reproduction on www.codesandbox.io

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa yes sir i'll add it here as soon

Comment: please after this link
todoList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("todo"));
add console.log(todoList)
fill some todo to list then refresh and show me what is in console

Comment: `addToDOM` is your render function, that puts whatever is in the `todoList` array to the screen. So call it immediately when the page is loaded!

Comment: (Other things: 1. You can just do `let todoList = JSON.parse(localStorage.get("todo"))`, no need to declare and reassign it separately. 2. You should initialize it in case the local storage is empty: `const todoList = JSON.parse(localStorage.get("todo") || "[]")`. 3. Uncomment the `todos.innerHTML = ""` line. 4. Note that setting the HTML content of an element from untrusted input can be a security vulnerability. 5. Checking todos won't persist, you have to store that in the `todoList` array somehow.)

Comment: i added just window.onload = addToDom() in the end of my code and everything is fixed! :) thanks to everyone for hints and answers 

Comment: `window.onload = addToDom()` is actually not the correct way to do it - the reason is the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7137401/8376184). But in this case it's fine to simply do `addToDOM()` on the top level of code.

Comment: @FZs Checking todos won't persist, you have to store that in the todoList array somehow.) –  How can i do this?

Comment: Instead of storing an array of strings as `todoList` you could make it an array of objects (having like `name` and `checked` as properties), and change `addToDOM` to also conditionally output `checked` classes.