# setTimeout -- callback executed immediately?

Tags: javascript, timeout, settimeout

I want to let an element fade in, and stay on the page for 7 seconds before it fades out. And I can cancel it anytime. 
I defined the following functions. But when I called `info_timeout.setup(ele, 'some msg here')`, the ele just faded in and faded out immediately.

Am I missing something?

```
var info_timeout = {
show_info: function(){
    this.ele.html(this.msg).fadeIn('normal');
    this.id = setTimeout(this.hide_info(), 7000);
},
hide_info: function(){
    console.log(this.ele, this.id);
    this.ele.fadeOut('slow');
    delete this.id;
},
setup: function(ele, msg) {
    this.ele = ele;
    this.msg = msg;
    this.cancel();
    this.show_info();
},
cancel: function() {
    if(typeof this.timeoutID == "number") {
        clearTimeout(this.id);
        delete this.id;
    }
}
```

};

Thanks.

Comment: this is asked a hundred times a day.

Comment: @zzzzBov Find dup. for a close. Most of the time I think it's just the horrid titles...

Comment: @pst, i completely agree about the titles, it's nearly impossible to find dupes of some questions because they're different code with the same issue, and the same answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037203/why-is-my-function-call-that-should-be-scheduled-by-settimeout-executed-immediat , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120781/settimeout-ignores-timeout-fires-immediately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several problems.

This invokes `hide_info` *right away*. **Parenthesis *invoke* a function-object!** (or are used for applying precedence to expressions).

That is,

```
this.id = setTimeout(this.hide_info(), 7000);
```

Is [mostly] equivalent to:

```
var temp = this.hide_info()       // call function ... uh, what?
this.id = setTimeout(temp, 7000)  // temp is "return" value ("undefined" here)
```

Oops! That's not right :) So *take away the parenthesis*. This will pass the function-object itself to the `setTimeout`. (Yes, functions are just objects in JavaScript. The expression `this.hide_info` is first *evaluated* to a function-object and, if there is a `(...)` after, it will invoke said function-object.)

```
this.id = setTimeout(this.hide_info, 7000)
```

However, it is *still* not correct because `this` inside the timeout function (`hide_info`) will be wrong! But this can be fixed with using a closure. (There are many great SO answers on the topic, feel free to search!)

```
var self = this
this.id = setTimeout(function () {
    // now in hide_info "this" will be "self", which was "this" ... outside :)
    self.hide_info()
}, 7000)
```

(Or use `Function.bind` from ECMAScript ed5 or a library.)

Additionally, `this.id` is not the same as `this.timeoutID`, and is suspect for "correctness".

Keep it simple. It's okay to pass undefined/0 to clearTimeout: it'll silently ignore you.

```
cancel : function () {
    clearTimeout(this.id)  // but id is a horrid overloaded name :)
    this.id = undefined
}
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate it. I just started playing with js, and the document on MDN doesn't explain that much.

Comment: Thans a lot. Appreciate the explanation