# Why won't this focus event trigger

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very simple html file that contains an `input` element. Whenever the `input` element is focused on, I want to `console.log` a message. What happens is, the console.log is fired immediately upon the loading of the page, and never again. I can't use inline `onfocus` and no jquery. Here is what I've tried.

first

```
<html>
<body id="fname" >
    <input id="fname" type="text" >
</body>
<script>        
    window.onload = () => document.getElementById("fname").addEventListener(`onfocus`,console.log(`hi`));
</script>
</html>
```

second

```
<html>
<body id="fname" >
    <input id="fname" type="text" >
</body>
<script>
    window.onload = () => document.getElementById("fname").onfocus = console.log(`hi`);
</script>
</html>
```

What gives?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setTimeout -- callback executed immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462381/settimeout-callback-executed-immediately)

Comment: The first argument to `addEventListener` should be `"focus"`, not `"onfocus"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you're not passing in a function to the `onfocus` event. Try this:

```
<html>
    <body id="someOtherId" >
        <input id="fname" type="text" >
    </body>
    <script>
        window.onload = () => document.getElementById("fname").onfocus = () => console.log(`hi`);
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: You still have the duplicated `id="fname"` on the body-element.

Answer (score 1):

The `console.log` statement is executed immediately,

To execute the listener `onfocus`, you want to wrap it in a function body:

```
document.getElementById("fname")
    .addEventListener(`onfocus`, () => console.log(`hi`) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a **duplicated id on the body** and didn't provide a function for the [onfocus-event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp).

A working version:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="text" >
    <input id="fname" type="text" >
  </body>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("fname").onfocus = function() {
      console.log("hi");
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

I added another input so you can switch between them and see the event fire only on the second one.