# Trying to understand a callback function

Tags: javascript, css, callback

I am trying to understand why my function is being executed before I get to the callback of my openModal script. I am fairly new to javascript but the understanding I had is that when you pass a function, it will execute when called *(i.e., my callback() function in the openModal function)*. I've looked at a number of other examples and it appears I have the correct structure but I must be missing something. Any guidance here would be helpful.

Order of events when calling openModal

- List item
- executes callback function
- closes other modals
- opens the current modal
- does nothing because the callback function is undefined *(why is it undefined?)*

Shouldn't the events unfold like this

- closes other modals
- opens the current modal
- executes callback function

Any guidance here is appreciated.

```
<script>
function openModal(modal, callback) {
    let modalCollection = document.getElementsByClassName(`modal`)
    if (modalCollection) {
        for (let index = 0; index < modalCollection.length; index++) {
            closeModal(modalCollection[index]);
        }
    }
    if (modal) {
        modal.style.display = `block`;
    }
    if (callback) {
        callback();
    }
}
</script>

openModal(modalContactDelete, openModalContactDeleteCallback(${element.ContactId}))
```

Comment: `openModalContactDeleteCallback(${element.ContactId})` is an immediate call to the callback function. It's called before `openModal()` is even invoked. A function name followed by a  parenthesized argument list is a function call.

Comment: When you do `openModalContactDeleteCallback(${element.ContactId})` you are *executing* the function, not passing a reference to it that will be executed later.

Comment: @Pointy do we have some sort of canonical for this? It feels like there should be - it shows up way too much. I think this is the fourth I saw *today*.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm sure I've seen it tons, but my google-fu is weak today.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling functions with setTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800512/calling-functions-with-settimeout)

Comment: Not a perfect dupe but I found it through [setTimeout — callback executed immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462381/settimeout-callback-executed-immediately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's invoked because you invoke it by `()`

You can try the following:

```
openModal(modalContactDelete, () => {
  openModalContactDeleteCallback(element.ContactId)
})
```

By that why, the callback will be an anonymous function, within it, you call your `openModalContactDeleteCallback`

Comment: Ah, I knew it had to be something simple. So I guess my confusion is here, could I technically call `openModal(modalContactDelete, () => { openModalContactDeleteCallback(element.contactId) }, openModalContactDeleteCallback(elementContactId) )` and it would not only execute immediately but on callback?

Comment: Yes, you can try it out. `openModalContactDeleteCallback` will be excecuted on your callback.

Comment: Okay, I think this is just a tad confusing for me (coming from C#). So methods aren't more on the dynamically defined side? I guess I just need to do more reading.