# Javascript setTimeout at onclick

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a javascript function at the onclick of an html element as shown below.
But not sure why the below timeout function is not working here.Any idea

```
onclick="setTimeout(rating(), 3000)"
```

Comment: If you search for (and write about) the *actual problem* then it's easier to find duplicates - "not working" is *not* a valid diagnosis.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137401/why-is-the-method-executed-immediately-when-i-use-settimeout?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120781/settimeout-ignores-timeout-fires-immediately

Comment: This code hurts my eyes. This is 2014 already, don't use `onclick` and look at that incorrect use of `setTimeout`.

Comment: @Derek I am new to javascript.if there is any better way then pls tell

Comment: Have a look at these articles to learn about the different ways to bind event handlers: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove parenthesis, change:

```
onclick="setTimeout(rating(), 3000)"
```

to

```
onclick="setTimeout(rating, 3000)"
```

or better way would be:

```
onclick = setTimeout(function() {
    rating();
}, 3000);
```

Comment: The "better way" is incorrect - it will spawn the timer first, then pass an (invalid) numeric value to the onclick property.

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="setTimeout(rating, 3000)" // rating without the ()
```

When you include the parentheses, the function return value is used instead of the function itself.