# setInterval and setTimeout don't seem to work with a console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am answering my own question in the hopes it will solve someone else's headache:

I could not get the following code to work:

```
function givePosition(){
    var place = $('#two').position();
    console.log(place);
}

window.setInterval(givePosition(), 50);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is a widely known thing and a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate.

Comment: The master canonical answer seems to be [Why is my function call that should be scheduled by setTimeout executed immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037203/why-is-my-function-call-that-should-be-scheduled-by-settimeout-executed-immediat), but the duplicate at [setTimeout ignores timeout? (Fires immediately)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120781/settimeout-ignores-timeout-fires-immediately) applied more directly to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was to give the function name as a parameter without parentheses, like so:

```
window.setInterval(functionName, 50);
```

instead of:

```
window.setInterval(functionName(), 50)
```

Comment: This is called passing a function reference, btw