# Why is this javascript code not working on IE 11?

Tags: javascript, dom, document, internet-explorer-11, addeventlistener

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.assign("http://www.google.com")
}, 3600000));
```

I suspect there is something about IE or IE 11, I need to know about because it works on MF, GC, and Safari.

I thought I read somewhere this should work for IE 9 and above!

In case people are wondering, I am trying to find a simple way to redirect people out of a website, if they have been inactive for too long.

Comment: Did you wait an hour after setting this?  If you log document.readyState immediately after this call, what does it show as?

Comment: Why do you think that code will work? Looks like an error to me. You are passing the timeout ID as the callback to an event listener. Either wrap it in an function, or remove the event listener entirely (your timeout function does not manipulate the DOM anyway).

Comment: I tested it and it still seems to work for much shorter timeout values.  It doesn't really seem to be the sane way to do it, but it should still set the timeout, I think.

Comment: @airza It "works", but is *independent* of the DOMContentLoaded event. That is the setTimeout is created *immediately* and the result of that function (an integer) is passed as the value to the listener's callback (which is incorrect, although I don't believe this would cause an exception .. but maybe browser differences?). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120781/settimeout-ignores-timeout-fires-immediately

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  setTimeout(function(){ window.location.assign("http://www.google.com"); }, 3600000);
});
```

The second arg to addEventListener should be a function.

Comment: I was using an anonymous function " ( ) => { ". In IE11 must be function () { 
Thank you.

Comment: @Leonardo ie11 doesn't support arrow functions, which is an ES6 feature. https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#ie11

Comment: Now I know it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're passing a `setTimeout` with a `addEventListener`. The `addEventListener` takes a function not a `setTimeout`.  **So the solution is to warp it up in a function** .

#### Wraping up in a function:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    window.location.assign("http://www.google.com") }, 3600000);
  }
);
```

**IE 9 and up support the `addEventListener`, but IE 8 and down go with the `attachEvent`**. So the code above should work just fine in your IE 11. But just for completeness:

```
document.attachEvent("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    window.location.assign("http://www.google.com") }, 3600000);
  }
);
```

Also, because you're code doesn't manipulate the DOM anyway, you can just do:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    window.location.assign("http://www.google.com") }, 3600000);
```

Answer (score -1):

IE support attachEvent instead of addEventListener

try this

```
document.attachEvent("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    window.location.assign("http://www.google.com") }, 3600000);
  }
);
```

Comment: IE has supported the standard addEventListener since IE9

Comment: I agree with @JaromandaX, IE 9 and up support the `addEventListener`.