# How can I make a part of code wait without halting everything else in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, timing

So, I need to make a function wait a time interval before executing, however, I need the rest of the code to execute while this wait is happening. Basically, I want to change variables in function of time passed without having to make all code wait for that to be executed.

I'll give an example so you can understand me better.

```
function example(){
    sampleCode();
}

var x = 0;

if(x > 0){
    console.log("enough time has passed")
}

example();
```

Take in mind that the whole block of code is being repeated multiple times a second, it's not a single execution program. I need to make x greater than 0 without preventing "example" from executing, so, setInterval is a nono (unless it has a functionality I'm not aware of). How can I do this? (Ignore the fact that x is being defined in this scope, so it's being set to 0 over and over, pretend it's a global variable).

EDIT: I've been recommended to use setTimeout and to show how I use it, here's how:

```
function handleMouseClick(evt){
    [...]
    setTimeout(test(), 3000);
}

function test(){
    alert("Testing");
}
```

This results in an instant display of alert, no matter how much time i put into the timeout. What's wrong?

Comment: Have you researched this?? `setTimeout` is what you want...

Comment: you need to learn about promises: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/promises-in-javascript-explained-277b98850de

Comment: @Studocwho I tried setTimeout, however, regardless of how much time I set it to wait, it always displays instantly and pauses everything else. This is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Are you running `setTimeout(10000)` then typing the rest of the code normally, or are you actually using it properly by providing a function and a wait time as arguments.

Comment: @Aplet123 Yes, I creted a dummy function that executes an alert to test it. I have it hooked up to the mouse click event, maybe that has something to do?

Comment: Show how you are using setTimeout I  your question. That is what we can help with. Otherwise your question is too broad.

Comment: @zero298 I edited the post, I'm trying to look for alternatives.

Comment: Remove the parentheses from test when you pass it to time out.

Comment: Remove the parentheses from your call to test in setTimeout. For example, setTimeout(test, 3000);

Comment: So setTimeout(test, 1000)

Comment: @PerpetualJ Oh my, this worked! Thanks a lot. You can post it as an aswer and I will mark it as such.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/4120781/691711

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue you have is that you are not properly using the setTimeout function. You need to remove the parentheses from your call.

```
setTimeout(test, 3000);
```

Downvoters; I will make a more thorough and detailed answer for future readers later today when I’m at a computer. I am currently on break and do not have my computer with me. You can view some of my other answers to set your mind at ease that I will be back to flesh out a more detailed answer.

Comment: This didn't age well. I'm happy to report that nowadays I feel stupid about this question tho.