# calling setTimeout with a for loop

Tags: javascript

I've written a function that changes the css positioning of a div

I've been successfully using setTimeout to call the function at a specific interval

NOW what I'm trying to do is call the function on 28 different divs on the same page, each with its own speed.

my thinking was that I could do this with a for loop like so:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 28; x++)
   { setInterval(function(){changeDirection(divlist[x])}, divs[divlist[x]].speed);}
```

using the object 'divs' where the speed and id  are stored

the only way I could get them all to move against the timer was to call setInterval 28 times like so...

```
setInterval(function(){changeDirection(divlist[1])}, divs[divlist[1]].speed);
setInterval(function(){changeDirection(divlist[2])}, divs[divlist[2]].speed);
setInterval(function(){changeDirection(divlist[3])}, divs[divlist[3]].speed);
setInterval(function(){changeDirection(divlist[4])}, divs[divlist[4]].speed);....etc
```

the for loop did NOT work...

does anyone have any idea why? and is there a way to call setInterval on many different functions with a loop like this

Comment: possible duplicate of [setTimeout in a for-loop and pass i as value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-a-for-loop-and-pass-i-as-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to "anchor" the value of your loop iterator, otherwise it keeps incrementing and all the intervals affect the 29th one, which doesn't exist.

```
for(var x=0; x<28; x++) {
    (function(x) {
        // code goes here
    })(x);
}
```

However, 28 timers on one page is a really bad idea. Consider rewriting your code so that you only have one interval that calculates the new positions based on the speed value.

Comment: great answer...thanks! I'm curious to know the reason why the timers are bad as it seems to work fine performance-wise

Comment: Firefox lags horribly when I have just six timers running simultaneously. Or at least it did last I tested.

Answer (score 1):

My approach to these self calling functions.

```
var i = -1;
(function cssPositioning() {
  i++;
  if ( i < 28 ) {
            changeDirection(divlist[i]);
    setInterval(cssPositioning, divs[divlist[i]].speed);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Kolink's explanation, you can try

```
for (var x = 0; x < 28; x++){ 
   setInterval(function(){
     var local = x;  //anchor the variable  
     changeDirection(divlist[local])}, divs[divlist[local]].speed);
   });
}
```

Hope this helps.