# How would I make setInterval pause the for loop it is in?

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/xDWLQ/

JavaScript:

```
var quotes = new Array();
quotes[0] = "message 0";
quotes[1] = "message 1";

var qText = document.getElementById('qText');
for (i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) {
    setInterval(function() { qText.innerHTML = quotes[i]; }, 2000);
}​
```

HTML:

```
<p class="qText" id="qText">Predefined text</p>​
```

The `innerHTML` of `qText` changes to undefined, instead of changing into `quotes[0]`, followed by `quotes1`. Now I tried debugging it by using `alert()` inside the setInterval function to give me the index of the for loop, and it said "2" both times. So, how would I have the for loop paused instead of setInterval creating new threads and incrementing the index?

Comment: You have a closure issue with quote[i] and you can't pause a loop.

Comment: instead of alert, use `console.log();` because its more flexible for outputting. (console log outputs to firebug, or whatever console you're using in your browser)

Comment: possible duplicate of [setTimeout in a for-loop and pass i as value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-a-for-loop-and-pass-i-as-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is you want, not a loop.

```
var quotes = ["message 0", "message 1"];
var qText = document.getElementById('qText');
var i = 0;
var len = quotes.length;

setInterval(function() {
   qText.innerHTML = quotes[i++];
   if (i === len) i = 0; 
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a completely different approach:

```
var quotes = ["message 0", "message 1"];
var qText = document.getElementById('qText');
var i = 0;

var update = function() {
    qText.innerHTML = quotes[i++ % quotes.length];
};

update();
setInterval(update, 2000);
```

Comment: @xdazz: The `% quotes.length` takes care of that :)

Comment: Hey, could I get an explanation for the downvote, whoever that was?

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce correct variable to be passed to the function by calling setInterval with a list of parameters passable to the function (tested on your jsfiddle)

```
setInterval(function(q) { qText.innerHTML = q; }, 2000, quotes[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

setInterval is already creating a loop, all its iterations will run after each n milliseconds, in your case 2000. If you are calling setInterval in a loop then its content will run in every n milliseconds i times. You just have to call it once. Note that Javascript is not multithreaded in browsers.