# jquery loop not triggering jquery functions

Tags: jquery

I searched through stackoverflow and various other sites and can't seem to get an answer to this dilemma.

My aim is to have jQuery functions applied to divs in succession using an array with div id's.

I have the following code that isn't working for some reason:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#click').click(function(){ 
        var layout_list = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'];
        load_delay = 50;
        for (i = 0; i < layout_list.length; i++ ) {
            load_delay =  load_delay+50;
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#l_"+layout_list[i]).css("visibility","visible");
                $("#l_"+layout_list[i]).addClass("bounceIn");
            },load_delay);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to use a closure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [setTimeout in a for-loop and pass i as value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-a-for-loop-and-pass-i-as-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a closure, e.g:

```
for (i = 0; i < layout_list.length; i++) {
    load_delay = load_delay + 50;
    (function (i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#l_" + layout_list[i]).css("visibility", "visible");
            $("#l_" + layout_list[i]).addClass("bounceIn");
        }, load_delay);
    }(i));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I feel like a complete noob now.
I have it up and running now.