# add div tags after specific amount of time repeatedly in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add append 10 div tags to another one but I need to wait random time before appending each one, something like this:

```
function start()
{
      for (var i= 0; i< 10; i++)
      {
          var time = generateRandomWaitingTime();
          sleep(time);
          $('#div1').append('<div> div num' + i + '</div>');
      }
}
```

I tried implementing my own sleep(time); function like [here](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/delay-sleep-pause-wait/) but it didn't work with me as it hangs any page event till the wait(time) finishes

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) and a [closure](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/closures/):

```
//closure
var addElement = function(i){
   return function(){
        $('#div1').append('<div> div num' + i + '</div>');
   };
};

function start() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var time = generateRandomWaitingTime();

        setTimeout(addElement(i), time);
    }
}
```

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JaR34/

## Update:

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JaR34/1/

Comment: You should use a closure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-a-for-loop-and-pass-i-as-value

Comment: this still will execute all 10 setTimout(addElement(i), time) statements at the same time.

assuming the time is constant 3 sec. for ex. It will produce this:

wait for 3 sec. then add all 10 elements 

while what I need is :
- wait 3 sec. 
- add one element
- wait 3 sec.
- add one element 
- and so on

Comment: @user2723364 in that case, you could use `setInterval` and then clear it once the counter reaches 10: http://jsfiddle.net/JaR34/1/

Comment: @Alvaro sorry I didn't make it clear, what I said about the assumption that time is constant was just to clarify that the code with setTimeout() will not perform a delay between each call for addElement(i) in the loop .. I still need random timing like this:" addElement(0) - wait 2 sec. - addElement(1) - wait 5 sec. - addElement(2) - wait 3 sec. -- "

Answer (score 1):

[setTimout()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) Seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: not really, setTimeout() is not executed in sequential way like the sleep() .. setTimeout will start but will not hold the for loop from continue till the time is over.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var elements = [1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000];

function generateRandomWaitingTime(){

    //will give you random index
    var index = Math.floor((Math.random()*elements.length));
    return (elements[index]);
}

function appendDiv(i){

    var time = generateRandomWaitingTime();

    setTimeout(function () {
       $('#div1').append('<div> div num' + i + '</div>');
    }, time);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    appendDiv(i)
}
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6neFA/1/

Comment: try to make elements array have only one value 2000 for ex. .. the page will wait for 2 sec. and all divs will be appended at the same time, I need every div to be appended after 2 sec. from the previous ones