# how to control for-loop exection in javascript [what should this javascript code do]

Tags: javascript

can anyone please help me to figure out what this code javaScript code means

```
  (function(){
  for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    setTimeout(console.log(i),1000);
  }
})();
```

Comment: @clentfort do you think that is gonna define the reason why this code is logging the values {0,1,2,3,4,} to the console at a time instead of waiting for 1000ms as defined in setTimeout ?

Comment: It doesn't wait for the timeout because you're passing the result of calling `console.log()` to `setTimeout` instead of passing a function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-a-for-loop-and-pass-i-as-value

Comment: why is my question rated Negative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code basically calls a function which is gonna log

0

1

2

3

4

A **single time**, why ? Because setTimeout is actually running `setTimeout(undefined, 1000)` 5 times, according to the return value of `console.log`, it will not evaluate a function, so the instruction is just lost.

Though from what I understand of what the code tries to say, to make the code work well, you could delegate the iteration control to a self calling function delayed with `setSimeout`

```
(function self(times, delay) {
    self.config = self.config || {
        times: times,
        delay: delay,
        iteration: 0
    };

    ++self.config.iteration;

    if (self.config.iteration <= self.config.times) {
        console.log(self.config.iteration);
        setTimeout(self, self.config.delay);
    }
})(5, 1000);
```

Comment: thanks 'aduch' your answer works as expected but i want to know why is not my code running or what does it means to the js engine

Comment: your answer really defines the reason but does it mean if i replace the console.log(i) which is returning the undefined, with a function returning the value of i . the code will work as expected ?

Comment: The first parameter of setTimeout must be a function or a string that will be evaled

Comment: what about setTimeout(test(i),1000);

function test(i)
{
return i;
}

Comment: `setTimeout(test(i),1000);` will not work `setTimeout(test.bind(null, i),1000);` will work because bind returns a function, but does not call it

Answer (score 2):

You have run into very common closure issue. To fix this you can have for example self invoked function. Also you should pass function handler to `setTimeout` instead of invoking `console.log`:

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    (function( i ) {
        setTimeout( function(  ) {
            console.log(i);
        },1000);
    })( i );
}
```

If you want to print to console numbers from 0 to 4 in 1000ms interval you should use `setInterval` function:

```
var intervalHandler = null
  , i = 0;
intervalHandler = setInterval( function() {
    console.log( i );
    if( i === 4 ) {
         clearInterval( intervalHandler );
         return;
    } 
    i++;
}, 1000 );
```

Comment: are you sure this will print the numbers to the console with a interval of 1000ms ?

Comment: This will not print them w/ interval of 1000ms, this will print them all after 1000ms. If you want to print numbers w/ interval you will need another functionality for this and probably use `setInterval` method or recursive `setTimeout`.

Comment: your comment is pretty close can you please elaborate it as i can understand it

Comment: @Constantine don't forget to accept answers if they was helpful and welcome to SO ;) Cheers.

Comment: i am sorry i dont have enough rank to rate up your comments

Comment: No, I mean accept answers. I saw you have 4 questions and non of the answers was accepted. See more info here http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer . It's check mark near the answer.

Comment: well the only reason why i haven't accepted a single answer is that no one answer helped as i was expecting from SO, but Mr.aduch's answer is really kind of i wanted and i surely will accept it after some more comments.

Answer (score 0):

`for(var i=0;i<5;i++)` //this code loop for five time before  it break.
 i.e, it will execute this function for five time `setTimeout(console.log(i),1000);`.
 setTimeout() is a javascript function for delay and it going to delayed for 1s and it going to carry      out action for `console.log(i);`.

Comment: i guess then it should make a delay 1000ms between logging the values