# For Loop with timeout

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to run a little script in my Browsers (Chrome) Javascript Console, which clicks some buttons to show me some links

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 300; i++) {
    expandPack("S" + i);
}
```

So to not ddos the site, I'd need a delay

The delay should be between every run of the expandPack function

So how to do this?

Thanks for your help

EDIT:

Okay, got it to work with this guys code

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3583754/3499442

didn't see it wen googling for it

Although Thank everyone for his help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop

Comment: Look up [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout).

Comment: OP doesn't want to artificially invoke a timeout, OP wants to defer the execution and break it into parts from what I understand. Please elaborate on what expandPack does and what browsers you have to support. A `WebWorker` might be a better solution to dispatch external work to a separate thread.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - `// DELAY HERE` sounds kike a time out to me.

Comment: @PM77-1 "So to not ddos the site, I'd need a delay" although OP probably didn't mean a _distributed dos :)

Comment: You could checkout this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-a-for-loop-and-pass-i-as-value

Comment: So, I want to run the Code in my Browsers Conbsole (Google Chrome) to bring up links on a website. I want a delay between every run of the expandPack function. I'll edit the post to clarify this, sorry guys :/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a timeout in a recursive function like this:

```
var delay = 100; //In Milliseconds
function loopExpand(count)
{
    expandPack("S" + count);
    if(count < 300)
        setTimeout(function(){loopExpand(count+1)}, delay);
}
```