# javascript loops: restore console after each iteration

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

I am currently working on code that when runs on Node.js logs only each of the values of the object below, delayed by one second on each iteration and concatenated with the string "you are now watching"

```
const episodes = [
  { id: 's06e01', title: 'Pilot' },
  { id: 's06e02', title: 'Top Banana' },
  { id: 's06e03', title: 'Charity Drive' },
  { id: 's06e04', title: 'Visiting Ours' },
  { id: 's06e05', title: 'My Mother, the Car' },
  { id: 's06e06', title: 'In God We Trust' },
  { id: 's06e07', title: 'Storming the castle' },
  { id: 's06e08', title: 'Pier Pressure' },
  { id: 's06e09', title: 'Public Relations' },
];
    const finaleEpisode = { id: 's06e10', title: 'Bringing Up Buster' };

const addToPlaylist = episodes.concat(finaleEpisode)
```

Below is where i managed to do just that but i am aware there is a much simpler way to do this, I intended to use a loop but was unable to find a way to restore the console log after each iteration. Therefore I used Asynchronous JS to delay the printing and clearing functions

```
console.log("You are Now Watching "  + addToPlaylist[0].id + ' ' + addToPlaylist[0].title);


setTimeout(function(){console.log('\033c'); }, 3000);

setTimeout(function(){console.log("You are Now Watching "  + addToPlaylist[1].id + ' ' + addToPlaylist[1].title); }, 4000);

setTimeout(function(){console.log('\033c'); }, 5000);

setTimeout(function(){console.log("You are Now Watching "  + addToPlaylist[2].id + ' ' + addToPlaylist[2].title); }, 6000);

setTimeout(function(){console.log('\033c'); }, 7000);

setTimeout(function(){console.log("You are Now Watching "  + addToPlaylist[3].id + ' ' + addToPlaylist[3].title); }, 8000);

setTimeout(function(){console.log('\033c'); }, 9000);

setTimeout(function(){console.log("You are Now Watching "  + addToPlaylist[4].id + ' ' + addToPlaylist[4].title); }, 10000);

setTimeout(function(){console.log('\033c'); }, 11000);

setTimeout(function(){console.log("You are Now Watching "  + addToPlaylist[5].id + ' ' + addToPlaylist[5].title); }, 12000);

setTimeout(function(){console.log('\033c'); }, 13000);

setTimeout(function(){console.log("You are Now Watching "  + addToPlaylist[6].id + ' ' + addToPlaylist[6].title); }, 14000);
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what the aim of this exercise is -sounds like an X/Y problem or perhaps a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293376/javascript-for-loop-with-timeout

Comment: What does "restore console log" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < addToPlaylist.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        // clears all characters printer on previous loop
        process.stdout.clearLine();

        // use \r at the end to return the cursor to the begining 
        process.stdout.write("You are Now Watching "  + addToPlaylist[i].id + ' ' + addToPlaylist[i].title + "\r");
    }, i * 2000);
}
```

Your solution was not really "restoring" the line printed via `console.log` btw.

Comment: Then what was it that my original code was really doing?

Comment: When I tried that in node, it was printing new lines, they were not visible at first, but then I tried scroll a bit and they were still there.

Answer (score 1):

```
function doTask(num, max) {
    console.log("do whatever you want with " + num);
    if(num < max) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            doTask(++num, max);
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Ok, this is recursive. Don't do it with max greater than some millions.