# How am I able to add timing to javascript that alters text every second?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like this code to count up from 0 to 940 (very fast) and alter the text every time it updates

Here's my code (inside my ***head*** tag):

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function sleep(milliseconds) {
        const date = Date.now();
        let currentDate = null;
        do {
          currentDate = Date.now();
        } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
      }
      function onLoad(){
        var x = document.getElementById("numberID");
        var n = 940;
        var text = "";
        for(i = 0;i < n + 1;i++){
          text = i;
          x.innerHTML = text;
          sleep(1);
        }
      }
    </script>
```

At the moment, it just waits a second then displays '940' on screen and doesn't display it counting up.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**Here's the code I recently put in, still doesn't work:**

```html
const x = document.getElementById("numberID");
      function newFrame(duration, start =  performance.now()) {
        requestAnimationFrame((now) => {
          const elapsed = now - start;
          x.innerText = Math.max(0, Math.min(duration, 
          Math.round(elapsed)));
          if(elapsed < duration)
              newFrame(duration, start);
          })
        }
      }
      newFrame(940);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript : For loop with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293376/javascript-for-loop-with-timeout)

Comment: the sleep function is doing nothing.

Comment: `setInterval(function { do_stuff(); }, 1000);`. You can't sleep in JavaScript, but simulate with a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Answer (score 5):

Using a while loop to "sleep" is going to block the page's thread and nothing else can happen in the meantime. This is considered bad practice.

`setTimeout` guarantees that **at least** the defined time has passed, but can take (much) longer. This is imprecise, and especially bad for shorter intervals. Same with `setInterval`. They're also not recommended for callbacks that involve updating the DOM.

What you need to do is use a [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

```
function newFrame(duration, start =  performance.now()) {
  requestAnimationFrame((now) => {
    const elapsed = now - start
    console.log(`time passed: ${elapsed} ms`)
    if(elapsed < duration)
        newFrame(duration, start)
  })
}
newFrame(940)
```

In your specific case, I'd replace the `console.log` statement put there for didactic purposes, with something along the lines of:

```
x.innerText = Math.max(0, Math.min(duration, Math.round(elapsed)))
```

---

**Here's what that would look like:**

```js
const x = document.getElementById("numberID")

function newFrame(duration, start =  performance.now()) {
  requestAnimationFrame((now) => {
    const elapsed = now - start
    x.innerText = Math.max(0, Math.min(duration, Math.round(elapsed)))
    if(elapsed < duration)
        newFrame(duration, start)
  })
}

newFrame(940)
```

```html
<span id="numberID"></span>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks - im just unsure of how to implement this? I'm relatively new to HTML and web development, so I was just wondering if you could help me at all in implementing this piece of code...? Thanks!

Comment: @HenryHudson I added a `console.log` statement, try and replace your JS code with mine and look at the DevTools console to see what happens. Then it will just be a matter of replacing my `console.log` with whatever actions you want. Probably a combination of `Math.round()` to get a cleaner number from `elapsed`, and of `.innerText` to put the number in your element.

Comment: does the whole page reload when a new frame happens?

Comment: It's all explained in the link: requestAnimationFrame happens every time the screen updates, and that's the only time you actually need to update anything. It's used in animation to create a smooth animation, otherwise an update can happen in between a repaint of the screen.

Comment: @Sheraff It's more pedagogic to put the code into a snippet for others to see what happens without having to copy-paste it into the devtools.

Comment: @HenryHudson the browsers try to be smart about this and only update what needs to be updated. But using `requestAnimationFrame` doesn't "make a frame happen", it just tells the browser to call this function *before it was going to draw a frame anyway*, so that you only (and precisely) make calculations when necessary.

Comment: @RickardElimää that's fair 

Comment: @Sheraff check my post - ive edited it with the code I put in from you.

Comment: @HenryHudson you should try and re-indent your code properly, it will make it more obvious what is wrong: you have one `}` too many. This error could also have been caught by looking at the DevTools console that will say something like `Unexpected token '}'` and even tell you which line in your code is responsible for the error.

Comment: @HenryHudson at this point, the problem comes from something else. I'd wager that if you haven't changed the structure of your code, you're still declaring `var x` within the scope of your `onload` function, and using it from my `newFrame` function  where it doesn't exist. So you'd either have to pass it as an argument, or just put everything in `onload` at the root / global level (outside of the function, just within the `<script>` tag).

Answer (score 0):

The `sleep` function is not doing anything, what you need is a `setTimeout` to display the text at every `x` milliseconds.

Something like the below will work.

```js
let x = null;
let timeout = null;
const changeText = (text) => {
  x.innerHTML = text;
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}

function onLoad() { 
 x = document.getElementById("numberID");
 const n = 940;
 const t = .01; // in seconds
 for( let i = 0; i <= n; i++) { 
  timeout = setTimeout( () => changeText((i+1).toString()), (t * i) * 1000);  
 }
 
}

onLoad();
```

```html
<span id="numberID"></span>
```

Comment: `setTimeout` is both imprecise and not recommended for callbacks that alter the DOM.