# Count up timer use javascript

Tags: javascript

I had a code below show count up timer. How can I get calculate to get day?

```js
function a() {

  var time;

  time = 0;

  setInterval((function () {

    var hour, min, sec, str;

    time++;

    var sec = time % 60;

    var min = (time - sec) / 60 % 60;

    var hour = (time - sec - (min * 60)) / 3600;

    var count = hour + ':' + ('0' + min).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + sec).slice(-2);

    $('.response-time').html(count);

  }), 1000);

};

a();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="response-time"></div>
```

Comment: you can use `var day = time / (24*60*60);`

Comment: note - setInterval does not guarantee that function will be called exactly every second, there could be fluctuations, so such method will go out of sync soon, it is better to store start time, in function get current time and calculate difference

Comment: as to @IłyaBursov's point, here's one of my answers on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59591214/how-am-i-able-to-add-timing-to-javascript-that-alters-text-every-second/59591423#59591423