# Javascript for loop (How to make it repeat forever)

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a for loop that is working, but when finished I want it to begin again and repeat this process !

```
for (var i = 0; i != 3; i = i + 1) {
    (function(index) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById(location[index]).style.background = color[index];            
        }, 1000 * index);
      })(i);
}
```

Comment: .......... `while` ................

Comment: But what you're really looking for to make it work with that timeout, is a recursive function

Comment: embed the loop in another loop

Comment: I have a problem with your code, but it is not about your problem. Why do you use the function(index) ? As I see you don't need it.

Comment: @RockOnGom: He's doing it [because of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-for-loop-does-not-print-consecutive-values)

Comment: Thanks @coolbotic I haven't encouraged this problem before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use any looping structure like `for` or `while`. Instead just make a function that gets invoked with the index to start it off, and then inside the callback, it increments the index and recursively invokes the same function. when the index gets to `3`, set it back to `0` before the recursive call.

```
function cycle(index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById(location[index]).style.background = color[index];

        index++; // Increment the index

        if (index >= 3) {
            index = 0; // Set it back to `0` when it reaches `3`
        }

        cycle(index); // recursively call `cycle()`

        //cycle(++index % 3);
    }, 1000);
}

cycle(0);
```

I used the `%` operator for a quick way to make sure it gets set back to `0` on the recursive call.

Comment: It would have had much more sense to use a `setInterval`. I don't think this kind of answer is worth to be made community wiki.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: I make all my answers community wiki. `setInterval` would work, but I wouldn't say *"much more sense"*. Just two different ways to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks this is all working now would it be possible when say index is at 2 is breaks from the loop runs a function then carry's on with the loop? Thanks James

Comment: @coolbotic: why does it need to break the loop? can't you just run the function when `index === 2`?

Comment: Ah didn't think of that will try it now thanks! I would place this under cycle(0); correct?

Comment: @coolbotic: No, it should go inside the `setTimeout` callback. If you want it to run after the style has been set, then put it just before `cycle(++index % 3)`

Comment: @squint Sorry this is late but I'm confused why there is a % there and how that is calling 'cycle()'? Thanks if you can help

Comment: @coolbotic: The `%` is the modulus operator as mentioned in the last sentence. It simply returns the remained when dividing the left number by the right. So when `index` is `0`, it gives, `0`. When `1`, it gives `1`. When `2`, it gives `2`. When `3`, it gives `0`. When `4`, it gives `1`... and so on. So you get `0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2...` passed to `cycle()` as `index` increments. I'll update the answer with a version that is perhaps more clear.

Answer (score 0):

you can use second for loop. in the second loop write how many times do you want to repeat first loop. Also you can use while loop.

Answer (score -1):

Embed the initial for loop in another for loop to make the loop repeat a certain number of time.

For example (where number is the `number` of times you wish your loop to repeat):

```
for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  for (var i = 0; i != 3; i = i + 1) {
    (function(index) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById(location[index]).style.background = color[index];            
      }, 1000 * index);
    })(i); 
  }      
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just use
`while (true) { // code block to be executed }`

Comment: And lockup the code execution? Did you look at what is OP actually trying to do?

Comment: Please add supporting details to your answer to improve it.