# no delay on settimeout loop

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout

I have function that reads a csv file and calculates the distance between two types of values "Client" and "Helper"

```
function readCSV(e){
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var helferList =[];
    var kundenList =[];
    if (!file) {
        console.log('file could not be read');
            return;
    }
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
            var contents = e.target.result;
            var result = $.csv.toArrays(contents);
        $('.output').append(",");
        for(i = 0; i< result.length; i++){
            if(result[i][0] =="Kunde"){
                kundenList.push(result[i]);
            }
            else if(result[i][0] =="Helfer"){
                helferList.push(result[i]);
                $('.output').append(result[i][1] + " "+ result[i][2] + ", ");
            }
        }
        $('.output').append("\n");
        console.log(kundenList.length);
        for(i = 0; i< kundenList.length; i++){
            $('.output').append(kundenList[i][1] + " "+ kundenList[i][2] + ", ");
            for(j=0; j <helferList.length;j++){
                setTimeout(getDistance(kundenList[i],helferList[j]),500);

            }
            $('.output').append("\n");
        }


    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

The problem I have is that I must have a delay between each distance calculation. For this reason I use:

```
 setTimeout(getDistance(kundenList[i],helferList[j]),500);
```

But it does not seem to work as there is no delay between the calculations

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-for-loop-does-not-print-consecutive-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to use a multiplicator because in your current code all functions will be fired passed 500 miliseconds, but not incremental. After 500 miliseconds of the `for()` execution all functions will be fired instantly.

To change this, make a multiplicator with a flag like this:

```
function readCSV(e){
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var helferList =[];
    var kundenList =[];
    if (!file) {
        console.log('file could not be read');
            return;
    }
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
            var contents = e.target.result;
            var result = $.csv.toArrays(contents);
        $('.output').append(",");
        for(i = 0; i< result.length; i++){
            if(result[i][0] =="Kunde"){
                kundenList.push(result[i]);
            }
            else if(result[i][0] =="Helfer"){
                helferList.push(result[i]);
                $('.output').append(result[i][1] + " "+ result[i][2] + ", ");
            }
        }
        $('.output').append("\n");
        console.log(kundenList.length);
        var k = 0;
        for(i = 0; i< kundenList.length; i++){
            $('.output').append(kundenList[i][1] + " "+ kundenList[i][2] + ", ");
            for(j=0; j <helferList.length;j++){
                // 500 * k = 500 * 1 | 500 * 2 | etc
                setTimeout(getDistance(kundenList[i],helferList[j]),(500 * k++));

            }
            $('.output').append("\n");
        }


    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

Comment: It only works, when I use an anonymous function  setTimeout(function(){getDistance(kundenList[i],helferList[j])},(500 * k++));    But then I have the problem, that the parameters are unknown or null when passed to getDistance.

Comment: I don't have enough information to help you with that error. The problem of delay is solved with my answer. To solve the other problem, please, create a new question with that.

Comment: I figured out the problem! I have to pass the getDistance() Function as a string.   setTimeout('getDistance("'+kundenAddress+'","'+helferAddress+'")',(2000 * k++));

Comment: That's a scope problem, glad to hear it's solved. :)