# I need a delay that isn't setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, delay

This is the code that I have and I want to make it so that the letters (sentence parameter) type themselves one by one. Not all at a time. I keep trying with setTimeout() but I can't do it so that it keeps it's progress. Please help.

```
var letters = [];

function typeOut(sentence, code) {
    $('body').append('<p id=' + code + '></p>');


    for (i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
        letters[i] = sentence[i];
        $('#' + code).append(letters[i]);
    }
}

typeOut("Hello World", 1);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may wish to try `setInterval` which fires at fixed time intervals.

Comment: I suppose you have this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5226285/3132718

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` seems perfect. I guess you are using it incorrectly.

```js
function typeOut(sentence) {
  var txt = document.body
    .appendChild(document.createElement('p'))
    .appendChild(document.createTextNode(''));
  var i = 0;
  (function typeLetter() {
    if(i < sentence.length) {
      txt.nodeValue += sentence[i];
      ++i;
      setTimeout(typeLetter, 100);
    }
  })();
}
typeOut("Hello World");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't believe you made it work. I'm not very good at it I guess... Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I had fun with this question....
I may have done a little more than you asked.
But I think you will like it.

See in [**this CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/rLqboQ).

My version of your `typeOut` function:

```
function typeOut(sentence, code) {
    $('body').append('<p id=' + code + '></p>');

    var i=0;
    var letterDelay = setInterval(function(){
        $('#' + code).append(sentence[i]);
        i++;
    }, $("#speed").val() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is many way to make this work could this solution for you work to

```js
 var letters = [];

function typeOut(sentence, code) {
    $('body').append('<p id=' + code + '></p>');
    self = this;
    self.currentIndex = 0;
    self.sentence = sentence;
    
   var write =  function (){
     if(self.currentIndex < sentence.length) {
          letter = sentence[self.currentIndex];
          $('#' + code).append(letter);
           self.currentIndex+=1;
     }else {
          clearInterval(self.writeHandler);
        }
    }
    
    self.writeHandler = setInterval(write, 500)
}

typeOut("Hello World", "div1");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="div1"></p>
```

here on jsbin [check this](https://jsbin.com/hitojavipe/1/edit?html,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

There really aren't that many options, the only thing suitable for this is timers, either `setTimout` or `setInterval`.

You could always use jQuery's `delay()` method, but internally it also uses `setTimeout`

```js
function typeOut(sentence, speed) {
    var p = $('<p />'), i = 0;
    $('body').append(p);
    
    (function go() {
        p.dequeue().append(sentence[i++]).delay(speed).queue(go);
    })();
}

typeOut("Hello World", 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why nobody remember that `setTimeout` accepts more than two arguments? It is very convenient feature. This is my version of `typeOut`.

```js
function typeOut(text) {
    var out = document.getElementById('out');
    out.innerHTML = '';
    setTimeout(function typeNext(i) { //internal function can be named
        out.innerHTML += text[i++];
        if (i < text.length)
            setTimeout(typeNext, 100, i);
    }, 100, 0); //3rd arg goes to the function
}
```

```html
<p id="out"></p>
<button type="button" onclick="typeOut('Hello World');">Type Out</button>
```

Comment: Because IE 9 and below didn't support the additional parameters to `setTimeout`, so we have the two parameter version locked in our heads.  Whenever possible, I like to stick to a 'universal subset' that works everywhere rather than remember environment specific differences.

Comment: IE 9 is almost gone and will go away finally. We cannot stick to deprecated stuff forever.