# Google Chrome's unpredictable behaviour on alert() function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events, settimeout, alert

As you can see a blocking kind of function like `alert()` produce its output **not in order** when is filled in event queue of Google Chrome's by `setTimeout()` function, based on this code:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {

 (function(index){ 

     setTimeout(function() { alert(index) }, 100);

 })(i);

}
```

- Why is that?
- Is it considered as a Google Chrome's bug?

There should be an explanation for that.

Comment: Separately: Say what result you're seeing, for clarity.

Comment: You're telling chrome to execute **6** times the `alert()` function *simultaneously* 100 milliseconds later. What do you expect?

Comment: I expect them to be printed in order just like other browsers...

Comment: Then your logic is wrong. It's weird to expect the computer to execute multiple things at the same time (no multithreading in js). You need to move the loop *inside* setTimeout to get the expected results.

Comment: Logic! dear, I set them in an order,  and they should be out like one another, 1,2,3...
Just like how Firefox deals with that, correctly.

Comment: Do you need the timeout function to be *inside* the loop? If you place the `setTimeout()` out of the loop it should work fine.

Comment: I didn't ask for code solution.

Comment: opera has this problem too

Comment: Yeah, chromium based browsers are the same in this manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, it makes sorta sense to expect that at any given *moment* (say, in millisecond precision), there's only one slot of execution, and any events (like `setTimeout` callbacks) that should happen at that *moment* should all be in a single queue. That seems to be the expectation of the OP here.

However, there's nothing that requires browsers to work this way, and the reality of how things get scheduled is much more complex, and also varies by browser.

So, best bet is to never rely on the relative ordering of any two events, no matter how much you think they should be predictable.

I have an archived blog post here about the peculiar nature of timers and my (similar) frustrations with them: https://web.archive.org/web/20151029223348/http://blog.getify.com/on-the-nature-of-timers