# Why doesn't the count up clock work?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.write(i);
    },(i*1000));
}
```

This is my code, it works except for the counting part. Every second it writes 10. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Search about **closures**

Comment: And event loops as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-for-loop-does-not-print-consecutive-values). When you are iterating like this value of `i` changes, before timeout function is executed, you need to copy `i` value for each execution.

The simplest solution is to pass it to a separate method, like so:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
   addToDocument(i);
}

function addToDocument(i){
 setTimeout(function(){
        document.write(i);
    },(i*1000));
}
```

The problem with javascript, unlike java is that it does not treat `i` as final inside clusure, that is why you need to copy it's value.

Comment: I hope it will solve your case, if so please close the issue:)