# javascript json getting data out, always say: "undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Hey guys I have a javascript file like this:

```
  // An object that holds all images and words.
var items = {
    "images": [
        {
            "imageLink": "elephant.png",
            "imageText": "Elephant"
        },
        {
            "imageLink": "rabbit.jpeg",
            "imageText": "Rabbit"
        },
        {
            "imageLink": "tiger.jpg",
            "imageText": "Tiger"
        },
        {
            "imageLink": "turtle.png",
            "imageText": "Turtle"
        }

    ]
};

// Hide the buttons from the screen

var hidebuttons = function() {
    document.getElementById("buttonWrapper").classList.add("hide");
};

var replaceTitle = function(title) {
    document.getElementById("header").firstElementChild.innerHTML = title;
}

var rotateImage = function() {
    console.log(items.images.length);
    for (i = 0; i < items.images.length; i++) {
        setInterval(function() {
          //  document.getElementById("imageToRotate").src= "img/" + items.images[i].imageLink;
            console.log(items.images);
            if (i === items.images.length -1) {
                i = 0;
            }
        }, 1000);

    }

}
```

and when I I use items.images it returns the follwoing in the console:

```
Array[4]
0:    Object
1:    Object
      imageLink: "rabbit.jpeg"
      imageText: "Rabbit"
     __proto__: Object
```

but whenerver I use

```
items.images[i] 
items.images.i
```

It always returns "undefined". Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? thanks for the help. Cheers!

Comment: Logic is flawed creating numerous `setInterval`.

Comment: are you trying to change image every second?

Comment: @xszaboj, that is exactly what I am trying to create. I had the setInterval outside the For loop first but then it only update once a second and the image didnt change.

Comment: Just increment a counter and when it gets to array length return it to zero. You don't want multiple `setInterval`

Comment: @charlietfl thanks mate that was exactly what I was trying to create. I guess I made a wrong choice with the for loop. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when the `setTimeout` callback runs, the value of `i` is already `i === items.images.length`. The reason is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-for-loop-does-not-print-consecutive-values). See this simplified:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(i);
    }, 100);
}
```

I assume you wanted something like a carousel, like this:

```js
var i = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    console.log(i);
    i = (i + 1) % 3;
}, 1000);
```

Btw you use `i` as a global variable instead of a local one, and you start several interval timers for no reason.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this:

```
var items = {
    "images": [
        {
            "imageLink": "elephant.png",
            "imageText": "Elephant"
        },
        {
            "imageLink": "rabbit.jpeg",
            "imageText": "Rabbit"
        },
        {
            "imageLink": "tiger.jpg",
            "imageText": "Tiger"
        },
        {
            "imageLink": "turtle.png",
            "imageText": "Turtle"
        }

    ]
};

var rotateImage = function() {
  var numberOfImages = items.images.length;
  var i =0;
        setInterval(function() {
          //runs every second;
          var image = items.images[i++];
          console.log(image); //your logic with image should be here
          if(i == numberOfImages){
            i = 0;
          }
        }, 1000);

    }
rotateImage();
```

Answer (score 1):

You ran into a pitfall: In JavaScript, variables are function-scoped. That means, your i has the value 4 when your setInterval gets fired (because the for loop is over then and will leave i at 4).

Or, what I think you try to do, you nested the code the wrong way so I rewrote it in the hope it does now, what you need:

```
var rotateImage = function() {
    var currentImageIndex = 0;

    setInterval(function() {
        console.log(items.images[currentImageIndex]); //do with it what you want.
        currentImageIndex++;
        if (currentImageIndex >= items.images.length) currentImageIndex = 0; //reached end. Reset counter
    }, 1000);
};
```

The function is a bit misnamed, if my guess is right, because it suggests that it performs only one cycle. It should be named startRotatingImages() or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be this: `for (i = 0; i < items.images.length; i++) {`

You haven't initialised `var i` in the for loop, so `i` is still undefined :)

EDIT: **Solved it.** Slightly different reason, but same problem. `i` only becomes defined after after you run `rotateImage()` for the first time. When it does become defined, its value is quickly set to 4, which overshoots the array by one (there are four items, and `i` would access the fifth).

Comment: no....`i` will be a global, not undefined

Answer (score 0):

After some advice from @charlietfl I got rid of the for loop and manually coded a counter which solved the problem. See the code below for the details.

```
  var rotateImage = function() {
    var i = 0;
    var interval = window.setInterval(function () {
            i++;
            document.getElementById("imageToRotate").src= "img/" + items.images[i].imageLink;

            if (i === items.images.length -1) {
                i = 0;
            }
    }, 125);
};
```