# CSS Clip-Path Animation with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, loops, clip-path

I try to animate the Clip-Path Property with JavaScript.

Means: It "grows" with help of SetTimeout.

I tried this, but it doesn't work.
http://jsfiddle.net/071dm2h3/8/

```
var el = document.getElementById("image")

function grow(i) {
    el.style.clipPath = "circle("+ i +"px at 190px 160px)";
}

var i;
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  setTimeout(grow(i), 400);
}
```

What am I missing here? Shouldn't the setTimeout change the value of I in every loop, so that I can see the result immediately?

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work, I rewrote your `setTimeout` to be around your loop to make the image grow.

```
setTimeout( function(){ 
 for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  grow(i)
 }
},400);
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/071dm2h3/16/)

Answer (score 0):

No, `setTimeout` fires once, and only once.  Additionally, the way you are using `setTimeout` will lead to unintended results.  You are basically saying:

> I want to call `grow(i)` 400 milliseconds from now 100 times.

That means that 400 milliseconds from now, `grow(i)` will be called 100 times **simultaneously**.  You don't want that, you want to call `grow(i) 100 times, waiting 400 milliseconds between each iteration.

Instead, you should either use `setInterval` which will wait a duration between each call or have each `setTimeout` schedule the next timeout after a duration.

Consider:

This will wait 2 seconds and then print `1,2,3,4` all at the same time.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 2000);
}
```

This will print each iteration after a duration:

```js
function iteration(i) {
  console.log(i);
  if (i > 3) return;
  setTimeout(() => iteration(i + 1), 500);
}

iteration(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

change you javascript to this

```
var el = document.getElementById("image")

function grow(i) {
console.log(i)
    el.style.clipPath = "circle("+ i +"px at 190px 160px)";
}

var i;
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  setTimeout( ((i) => () =>  grow(i))(i), i*10);
}
```

and kindly read this once 
[setTimeout in for-loop does not print consecutive values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-for-loop-does-not-print-consecutive-values)