# How to assign x, y dinamic values to scrollTo() method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I try to get the values form Button elements:

```
<script>
    var elmnt = document.getElementById('<%= Button1.ClientID %>');
    var elmnt2 = document.getElementById('<%= Button2.ClientID %>');
    var x = elmnt.scrollLeft;
    var y = elmnt.scrollTop;
    var x2 = elmnt2.scrollLeft;
    var y2 = elmnt2.scrollTop;
    function ToTopOfPage(sender, args) { setTimeout("window.scrollTo(x, y)", 0); }
    function ToTopOfPage2(sender, args) { setTimeout("window.scrollTo(x2, y2)", 0); }

</script>
```

When I click on the Button1 or Button2 does not jump to the element   Here is the Button codes:

Button1:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, Page.GetType(), "ToTheTop", "ToTopOfPage();", true);
```

Button2:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, Page.GetType(), "ToTheTop", "ToTopOfPage2();", true);
```

---

When I add some values to scrollTo() method for example window.scrollTo(2000,1000) the method works fine but when I assign a dinamic value does not work window.scrollTo(x,y).

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout takes a function as its first parameter, and variables as the 3rd/4th/... parameter. Apparently it can convert a string containing function and parameters, but you really should forget that, and do something like:

```
function ToTopOfPage(sender, x, y) {
    setTimeout(window.scrollTo, 0, x, y); 
}
```

EDIT: I find it hard to believe that it works with hardcoded values and the whole lot as a string, but not when it's done with variables. You may want to recheck your variables:

```
function testScrollTo(x,y) {
    console.log("x: ", x);
    console.log("y: ", y);
    window.scrollTo(x,y);
}

function ToTopOfPage(sender, x, y) {
    setTimeout(testScrollTo, 0, x, y); 
}
```

Comment: This doesn`t work for me just when instead of x, y I give a fix value.

Comment: Are you saying my answer doesn`t work for you, and only a fixed value works?

Comment: Yes, for example setTimeout(window.scrollTo, 0, 2000,1000);  this brings the button to a position but when I assign the variables setTimeout(window.scrollTo, 0,x,y); nothing happening.

Comment: I think you should console.log your variables to check them. Also be aware that you only pass a reference, ie. the value itself may change... eg. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-for-loop-does-not-print-consecutive-values

Comment: There is no problem with setTimeout, the problem is with the scrollTo() method somehow does not recognize assigned variables just numbers.