# Unable to iterate through timeout value using setTimeout in for loop

Tags: javascript

I need to loop through a series of setTimeout functions, iteratively changing the function argument and the timeout value.

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-for-loop-does-not-print-consecutive-values), setTimeout performs (apparently) oddly in a for loop when printing values. You can use `let` or define another function to resolve.

This works as expected: printing i every second

```
function doSetTimeout(i) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, i * 1000);
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
    doSetTimeout(i);
```

This does not work as expected: printing i sequentially every second, five seconds, second, etc. Instead of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, it logs 4, 0, 2, 1, 3 in the browser console.

```
times = [1,5,1,5];
function doSetTimeout(i) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, times[i] * 1000);
}

for (var i = 0; i <= 4; ++i)
    doSetTimeout(i);
```

I've experimented with using `let` and an anonymous function and also not been successful.

Comment: your `times` array has indexes from 0 to 4, so you should rather iterate like that: `for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i)`

Comment: Change **var** to  **let** This  is drawback for var variable . Read difference between var and let then you ll come to know. If you want to use var then use **self invoking fun** to preserve value of **I**

Comment: @Joel, thank you. Corrected, my apologies for not putting together a good example, however, problem remains. If you copy that chunk into the browser console (atleast chrome or firefox)it returns 4, 0, 2, 1, 3, not 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: @vipulpatel thanks, that may be the key but as I've mentioned, I couldn't get it to work with let either. Can you edit the code I provided?

Comment: @RyGuy , i have answered. Put given code in you doSetTimeout method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to realize that I had to add the previous times to the total to get the sequential waits. This works:

```
previous = 0;
times = [1000,5000,1000,5000];

function doSetTimeout(i) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, times[i] + previous);
    previous += times[i]
}

for (var i = 0; i <= 3; ++i)
    doSetTimeout(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in your dosetTimeout method : As i mentioned in comment

// capture the current state of 'i'
    // by invoking a function with its current value

```
(function(i) {
        setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, times[i] * 1000)
})(i);
```

Comment: Thanks @vipulpatel, I'm still getting an unordered list. Perhaps you could provide a full working code example?

Comment: It prints unordered because set timeoit gets called after time[i] * 1000. Noe first 1*1000  and at last 5*1000 gets called. So orderlist changed.

Answer (score 0):

I coded a quick solution based on your example.

```js
var i = 0;
var times = [1,5,1,5];

function wait(milleseconds) {
       return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milleseconds))
}

async function myLoop (times,i) {
    await wait(times[i]*1000);
  i++;
  alert('HI');
  if(i<times.length)
  myLoop(times,i);
}

myLoop(times,i);
```