# Why does my setTimeout function not logging the way I expected?

Tags: javascript

Say

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  var iteration = i;
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(iteration); }, i*1000);
}
```

I thought the above function would log as 0,1,2. But it logs out 2,2,2. Can anyone helps me to explain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setTimeout in for-loop does not print consecutive values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226285/settimeout-in-for-loop-does-not-print-consecutive-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three iterations of your loop run all at once, and you're scheduling the callback of `setTimeout()` to occur in the future.

By the time they run, `i` already has the value of `2`.

In other words, `setTimeout()` doesn't block the loop.